# sed in-place flag that works both on Mac (BSD) and Linux

Tags: linux, macos, sed, bsd

Is there an invocation of `sed` todo in-place editing without backups that works both on Linux and Mac? While the BSD `sed` shipped with OS X seems to need `sed -i '' …`, the GNU `sed` Linux distributions usually come with interprets the quotes as empty input file name (instead of the backup extension), and needs `sed -i …` instead.

Is there any command line syntax which works with both flavors, so I can use the same script on both systems?

Comment: Is perl not an option? *Must* you use sed?

Comment: Maybe install the GNU version and use that! http://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/? I'd try that first. Then again, that kind of sucks too.

Comment: @dimadima: Might be interesting to some other people browsing this question who have personal scripts that break on their OS X machine. In my case, though, I needed it for the build system of an open source project, where telling your user to install GNU sed first would have defeated the original purpose of this exercise (patch a few files in a "works everywhere" fashion).

Comment: @klickverbot yeah, makes sense. I first added the comment as an answer, and then deleted it, realizing it wasn't an answer to your question :).

Comment: Cross reference: [How to achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895/20807) on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.

Comment: In particular, this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92896/43390 does not use `-i`, and instead writes to a temporary file that it then `&& mv` to the source file.

Comment: I have a Linux/macOS/BSD solution to this in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65497543/117471

Answer (score 322, accepted):

If you really want to just use `sed -i` the 'easy' way, the following DOES work on both GNU and BSD/Mac `sed`:

```bash
sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/' filename
```

Note the lack of space and the dot.

Proof:

```bash
# GNU sed
% sed --version | head -1
GNU sed version 4.2.1
% echo 'foo' > file
% sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/' ./file
% ls
file  file.bak
% cat ./file
bar

# BSD sed
% sed --version 2>&1 | head -1
sed: illegal option -- -
% echo 'foo' > file
% sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/' ./file
% ls
file  file.bak
% cat ./file
bar
```

Obviously you could then just delete the `.bak` files.

Comment: This is the way to go. Add a few characters, and it's portable. Deleting the backup file is trivial (you already have the filename when invoking `sed`)

Comment: This worked on mac, but on ubuntu 16.04 it overwrite the original file to 0 bytes and creates the the .bak file also with 0 bytes ?

Comment: Of note, on macOS Sierra (and possibly earlier, I don't have a machine handy), `sed` does not accept a positional `command` argument when invoked with `-i` — it *must* be supplied with another flag, `-e`. Thus, the command becomes: `sed -i.bak -e 's/foo/bar/' filename`

Comment: This creates backups, while the OP specifically asks for in-place editing.

Comment: So the full solution is: `sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/' file && rm file.bak`

Comment: Note that the dot doesn’t really matter. You could say ``sed -ibak 's/foo/bar/' kinefile`` and it would create `kinefilebak` rather than `kinefile.bak`. As long as you `rm $1bak` instead of `rm $1.bak`, it works fine. (Granted, `xyz.bak` files jump out at you a little bit more than `xyzbak` files in an `ls` listing, `*.bak` “feels” more natural than `*bak`, and, if the filename is in `$f`, then you have to say `"${f}bak"` rather than the simpler `"$f.bak"`.)

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune That's true but the sed that comes with macOS doesn't have that option so what do you expect? One has to do it the way given and then move the file. Of course `sed -i` at the lower level also doesn't do an in place edit. How could it?

Comment: @Pryftan take a look at the answer from dnadlinger below...

Answer (score 133):

This works with GNU sed, but not on OS X:

```bash
sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/' target.file
sed -i'' -e 's/foo/bar/' target.file
```

This works on OS X, but not with GNU sed:

```bash
sed -i '' -e 's/foo/bar/' target.file
```

On OS X you

- can't use `sed -i -e` since the extension of the backup file would be set to `-e`
- can't use `sed -i'' -e` for the same reasons—it needs a space between `-i` and `''`.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Tells sed that the next argument is a command - could also be skipped here.

Comment: Note that `-i` and `-i''` are identical at shell parsing time; `sed` _can’t_ behave differently on those two first invocations, because it gets the exact same arguments.

Answer (score 54):

When on OSX, I always install GNU sed version via Homebrew, to avoid problems in scripts, because most scripts were written for GNU sed versions.

```bash
brew install gnu-sed --with-default-names
```

Then your BSD sed will be replaced by GNU sed.

Alternatively, you can install without default-names, but then:

- Change your `PATH` as instructed after installing `gnu-sed`
- Do check in your scripts to chose between `gsed` or `sed` depending on your system

Comment: the `--with-default-names` was [removed from homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/search?q=default-names%20created%3A2019-01-01..2019-01-10&unscoped_q=default-names%20created%3A2019-01-01..2019-01-10&type=Commits), more info in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/88812) answer.
when installing `gnu-sed` now, the installation instructions specify that you need to add `gnubin` to your `PATH`: `PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`

Comment: The page for the homebrew package -- https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils -- recommends adding this to your `bashrc` if you want them in your path before Mac tools of the same name: `PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`

Comment: You can also add `alias sed=gsed` in your RC files .

Answer (score 29):

As [Noufal Ibrahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229602/noufal-ibrahim) asks, why can't you use Perl? Any Mac will have Perl, and there are very few Linux or BSD distributions that don't include some version of Perl in the base system.  One of the only environments that might actually lack Perl would be BusyBox (which works like GNU/Linux for `-i`, except that no backup extension can be specified).

As [ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35060/ismail) recommends,

> Since perl is available everywhere I just do `perl -pi -e s,foo,bar,g target.file`

and this seems like a better solution in almost any case than scripts, aliases, or other workarounds to deal with the fundamental incompatibility of `sed -i` between GNU/Linux and BSD/Mac.

Comment: I love this solution. `perl` is part of the Linux Standard Base specification since May 1, 2009. http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Languages/LSB-Languages/perllocation.html

Comment: This is easily the best solution for portability

Answer (score 23):

Here's another version that works on Linux and macOS without using `eval` and without having to delete backup files. It uses Bash arrays for storing the `sed` parameters, which is cleaner than using `eval`:

```bash
# Default case for Linux sed, just use "-i"
sedi=(-i)
case "$(uname)" in
  # For macOS, use two parameters
  Darwin*) sedi=(-i "")
esac

# Expand the parameters in the actual call to "sed"
sed "${sedi[@]}" -e 's/foo/bar/' target.file
```

This does not create a backup file, neither a file with appended quotes.

Comment: this is the correct answer. I would simplify it a bit, but the idea works perfectly

`sedi=(-i) && [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ] && sedi=(-i '')`

`sed "${sedi[@]}" -e 's/foo/bar/' target.file`

Comment: Good stuff! I prefer the longer version for readability, though.

Comment: This a best way for me  to be compatible  with  different  system.

Comment: This fails if you’ve installed a GNU `sed` on the system (e.g. using MacPorts or Brew).

Answer (score 18):

***Answer:*** No.

The originally accepted answer actually doesn't do what is requested (as noted in the comments). (I found this answer when looking for the reason a `file-e` was appearing "randomly" in my directories.)

There is apparently no way of getting `sed -i` to work consistently on both MacOS and Linuces.

My recommendation, for what it is worth, is not to update-in-place with `sed` (which has complex failure modes), but to generate new files and rename them afterwards.  In other words: avoid `-i`.

Answer (score 18):

There is no way to have it working.

One way is to use a temporary file like:

```bash
TMP_FILE=`mktemp /tmp/config.XXXXXXXXXX`
sed -e "s/abc/def/" some/file > $TMP_FILE
mv $TMP_FILE some/file
```

This works on both

Comment: Is there a reason that

    SOME_FILE="$(sed -s "s/abc/def/" some/file)"; 
    echo "$SOME_FILE" > some/file;

won't work instead

Comment: Looks like you would be limited by the maximum size of a bash variable, no ? Not sure it will work with GBs files.

Comment: If you are creating a temporary file, why not just give an extension to create a backup file (which you can then remove) as @kine suggests below?

Answer (score 15):

The `-i` option is not part of [POSIX Sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html). A more portable method would be
to use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/alfa/bravo/|x' file
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` replace
3. `x` save and close

Comment: This is the correct answer.  A key feature of POSIX is portability.

Answer (score 7):

[Steve Powell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326416/304330) is quite correct, consulting the MAN page for sed on OSX and Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) highlights the in-compatibility within 'in-place' sed usage across the two operating systems.

JFYI, there should be no space between the -i and any quotes (which denote an empty file extension) using the Linux version of sed, thus

[sed Linux Man Page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

```
#Linux
sed -i""
```

and

[sed OSX Man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html)

```
#OSX (notice the space after the '-i' argument)
sed -i ""
```

I got round this in a script by using an alias'd command and the OS-name output of '**uname**' within a bash 'if'. Trying to store OS-dependant command strings in variables was hit and miss when interpreting the quotes. The use of '**shopt -s expand_aliases**' is necessary in order to expand/use the aliases defined within your script. shopt's usage is dealt with [here](http://chiefsandendians.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/linux-scripts-and-alias.html).

Answer (score 7):

Portable script for both GNU systems and OSX:

```
if [[ $(uname) == "Darwin" ]]; then
    SP=" " # Needed for portability with sed
fi

sed -i${SP}'' -e "s/foo/bar/g" -e "s/ping/pong/g" foobar.txt
```

Comment: There's no reason to put quotes around `"Darwin"` -- it can't parse to anything but itself. Whereas if it weren't for `[[ ]]`'s special semantics, you _would_ need quotes around `$(uname)` to ensure correct behavior with all possible return values.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem. The only quick solution was to replace the sed in mac to the gnu version:

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

Comment: This duplicates an existing answer with much more detail from 2015.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do `sed` in-place in a `bash` script, and you do NOT want the in-place to result with .bkp files, and you have a way to detect the os (say, using [ostype.sh](https://github.com/openframeworks/apothecary/blob/master/apothecary/ostype.sh)), -- then the following hack with the `bash` shell built-in `eval` should work:

```bash
OSTYPE="$(bash ostype.sh)"

cat > myfile.txt <<"EOF"
1111
2222
EOF

if [ "$OSTYPE" == "osx" ]; then
  ISED='-i ""'
else # $OSTYPE == linux64
  ISED='-i""'
fi

eval sed $ISED 's/2222/bbbb/g' myfile.txt
ls 
# GNU and OSX: still only myfile.txt there

cat myfile.txt
# GNU and OSX: both print:
# 1111
# bbbb

# NOTE: 
# if you just use `sed $ISED 's/2222/bbbb/g' myfile.txt` without `eval`,
# then you will get a backup file with quotations in the file name, 
# - that is, `myfile.txt""`
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `sed` is a *stream* editor, therefore in-place editing is a non-POSIX extension and everybody may implement it differently. That means for in-place editing you should use `ed` for best portability. E.g.

```
ed -s foobar.txt <<<$',s/foo/bar/g\nw'
```

Also see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sponge. Sponge is an old unix program, found in moreutils package (both in ubuntu and probably debian, and in homebrew in mac).

It will buffer all the content from the pipe, wait until the pipe is close (probably meaning that the input file is already close) and then overwrite:

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge):

> Synopsis
>
> sed '...' file | grep '...' | sponge file

Comment: Nice approach – unfortunately doesn't really help in the original situation as the reason for resorting to sed was to have something to use in a cross-platform helper script used on client machines, where you can't depend on anything else but the system tools being installed. Might be helpful to somebody else, though.

Answer (score -3):

The following works for me on Linux and OS X:

`sed -i' ' <expr> <file>`

e.g. for a file `f` containing `aaabbaaba`

`sed -i' ' 's/b/c/g' f`

yields `aaaccaaca` on both Linux and Mac. Note there is a quoted string *containing a space*, with *no space* between the `-i` and the string. Single or double quotes both work.

On Linux I am using `bash` version 4.3.11 under Ubuntu 14.04.4 and on the Mac version 3.2.57 under OS X 10.11.4 El Capitan (Darwin 15.4.0).

Comment: Wow, I'm glad I didn't listen to everyone above saying it was impossible and kept reading! This really just works. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Mac OS... new file with space appended to the end of the filename is created

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Mac either (/usr/bin/sed) - I now have an extra backup file with a space appended to the file name :-(

Comment: Try taking the space out of the single quotes, it works for me.