# How to remove an entry from the history in ZSH

Tags: zsh

Let's say I ran a command using a zsh

`echo "mysecret" > file`

I can easily print the history including the entry numbers using the command `fc -l`:

> ```
> 1  echo "mysecret" >| file
> ```

But how can I easily delete an entry from the history?

I cannot find a corresponding paragraph in **man zshbuiltins**.

Comment: What is this doing on StackOverflow as opposed to SuperUser?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771958/delete-specific-line-from-zsh-history/63494728

Answer (score 133):

#### *BSD/Darwin (macOS):

```
LC_ALL=C sed -i '' '/porn/d' $HISTFILE
```

#### Linux (GNU sed):

```
LC_ALL=C sed -i '/porn/d' $HISTFILE
```

This will remove all lines matching "porn" from your $HISTFILE.

With `setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE`, you can prepend the above command with a space character to prevent it from being written to $HISTFILE.

As [Tim pointed out in his comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243983/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-the-history-in-zsh/13661794?noredirect=1#comment39805395_13661794), the prefix LC_ALL=C prevents 'illegal byte sequence' failure.

Comment: NB on osx/BSD you need to put empty quotes after the -i  to explicitly specify no backup file, thus: `sed -i '' '/S3_SECRET/d' $HISTFILE`. This won't work on linux. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux

Comment: And if you get 'illegal byte sequence' then set LC_ALL=C, thus: `LC_ALL=C sed -i '' '/S3_SECRET/d' $HISTFILE` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287564/getting-sed-error-illegal-byte-sequence-in-bash

Comment: Don't forget to reload zsh, with `source .zshrc`.

Answer (score 86):

I don't know if there is some elegant method for doing this, but in similar situations I have logged out (allowing zsh to empty its buffer and write my history to file), then logged in, and finally **manually edited** `~/.zsh_history`, deleting the "dangerous" line.

Comment: Worked for me. I did have to restart my terminal for it picked up on the changes.

Comment: For bonus points, avoid loading the history file by setting the environment variable `HISTFILE=/dev/null`, or just use another shell. If `zsh` is the login shell, login and `exec sh`, then edit `~/.zhistory`.

Comment: It does work! remove command from  `~/.zsh_history`, then restart zsh.

Answer (score 46):

If you use the HIST_IGNORE_SPACE option in zsh you can prepend commands with a space " " and they will not be remembered in the history file. If you have secret commands you commonly use you can do something along the lines of: [alias hiddencommand=' hiddencommand'](https://web.archive.org/web/20160319033617/unsyncopated.com/blog/index.php/2007/08/18/omitting-certain-commands-from-zshs-history/).

Comment: put `setopt histignorespace` in your `~/.zshrc`

Comment: Thanks for `histignorespace`. Very useful !

Answer (score 14):

If you only want to make an **occasional deletion**, I think that  it's easier to **manually edit** your `.zsh_history`.

In a zsh terminal:

1. Close the terminal session with the command to delete.
2. open a new session,
3. **open** `~/.zsh_history` with a text editor (pico, Emacs, vim...),
4. **delete the faulty lines**,
5. close the editor, close the terminal session and open a new one,
6. enter `history` and the unwanted history item will be gone.

(Make sure the editor hasn't backed up the previous .zsh_history instance.)

(Solution based on https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/zn87awopb4-delete-a-command-from-zsh-history-)

Answer (score 8):

This function will remove any one line you want from your Zsh history, no questions asked:

```bash
# Accepts one history line number as argument.
# Use `dc -1` to remove the last line.
dc () {
  # Prevent the specified history line from being 
  # saved.
  local HISTORY_IGNORE="${(b)$(fc -ln $1 $1)}"

  # Write out the history to file, excluding lines that
  # match `$HISTORY_IGNORE`.
  fc -W

  # Dispose of the current history and read the new 
  # history from file.
  fc -p $HISTFILE $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST

  # TA-DA!
  print "Deleted '$HISTORY_IGNORE' from history."
}
```

---

If you want to additionally prevent all `dc` commands from being written to history, add the following in your `~/.zshrc` file:

```bash
zshaddhistory() {
 [[ $1 != 'dc '* ]]
}
```

---

## Update

I've now published a more comprehensive solution as a plugin: https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-hist

Answer (score 5):

**tldr:**

```
vi $HISTFILE
```

**more details:**

run `vi $HISTFILE`

SHIFT + g — to go to the end

dd — to remove line

:wq — to save and exit

reload session or open a new tab to see changes

Comment: how to reload a ZSH session?