# Delete specific line from Zsh history

Tags: macos, zsh

I'd like to remove a specific entry in my Zsh history.

Zsh's `fc` and `history` don't have any options to delete entries. I've tried looking for the `~/.zhistory` but that doesn't exist. How can I go about finding the location of the history file and remove the entry?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243983/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-the-history-in-zsh . Oh-My-Zsh is just an add-on for Zsh. It doesn't change anything about how Zsh's history works.

Comment: omz does replace `history` with `omz_history` via an alias.

Answer (score 84):

You are looking in wrong File. Look at `~/.zsh_history` not `~/.zhistory` To view in which file your history is saved:

```
echo $HISTFILE
```

And delete:

```
rm $HISTFILE
```

Comment: Note that you have to log out and back in after `rm $HISTFILE` to see the changes. This doesn't answer the question though. It's not about deleting the whole history (`history -c`), it's about deleting a specific line (`history -d [offset]`).

Comment: `echo $HISTFILE` goes to my bash history. ~/.zsh_history doesn't seem to have the entry I want to delete where else could it be?

Comment: Are you using `zsh`? If I `echo $HISTFILE` under both bash and zsh, I get different results.

Comment: Yes I'm using zsh with oh-my-zsh, but looks like `echo $HISTFILE` points to my bash history file.

Comment: This did not work for me at all - even with the file removed, history still shows the same output. It does not appear to have any correlation to $HISTFILE at all.

Comment: this is a serious bug... I should be able to delete a specific entry from the history imho.

Answer (score 55):

### Clearing Zsh History *(oh-my-zsh)*

---

- close, quit and re-open iTerm
- run `nano .zsh_history`
- use the `arrow keys` to navigate to the part of your history you'd like to delete.
- use the `delete` key to remove all unwanted history logs.
- Once you've removed everything you'd like to remove, select `control X` to `Exit`.
- You'll be prompted to `Save` the changes. If you're happy with your changes click `shift Y`.
- You'll be asked where you'd like to save your changes. Select `control T` to save `to File`.
- navigate to your `.zsh_profile` with your `arrow keys` and press enter.
- Quit and restart iTerm.
- type `history` to confirm the deletions.
- You've successfully cleared your Zsh history.

[osx](/questions/tagged/osx)[terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal)[zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh)[oh-my-zsh](/questions/tagged/oh-my-zsh)

Comment: Also vi with 
/thing to find.
I don't know if that also works with nano.

Answer (score 24):

Clear zsh history on unix systems.

```
 echo "" > ~/.zsh_history & exec $SHELL -l
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use these commands to open the ZSH command's history(When you are in the home or ~ directory) and assume that  you know how to use `vim` or `nano` :

```
nano ~/.zsh_history
vim ~/.zsh_history
open ~/.zsh_history
```

then you can delete the lines you want manually and save the file.

and if your zsh_history list is too long, for convenience use this:

1. enable mouse move and line numbering in the `Vim` environment by adding this to `.vimrc`:
2. open `.vimrc`:

> ```
>  vim ~/.vimrc
> ```

3. add these to `.vimrc` and save it(press ESC, enter ":" , write wq, and press enter):

> ```
> :set number
> set mouse=a
> ```

3. use the mouse to scroll easily in `zsh_history` by using `Vim`.
4. if you want to enable copy in `Vim` use holding shift on the keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

1. open  `~/.zshrc`
2. add the following line

   ```
   alias clear_history='echo "" > ~/.zsh_history & exec $SHELL -l'
   ```
3. Save and close the file
4. Close the console or type `zsh`
   *if you to see the result directly, but this will open another zsh shell in the old one*
5. Now you can clear the console typing `clear_history`

*All the previous answers are good, this is simply the solution that worked for me.*

Comment: Really handly and helpful answer.

Answer (score 6):

This function will remove any one line you want from your Zsh history, no questions asked:

```bash
# Accepts one history line number as argument.
# Alternatively, you can do `dc -1` to remove the last line.
dc () {
  # Prevent the specified history line from being saved.
  local HISTORY_IGNORE="${(b)$(fc -ln $1 $1)}"

  # Write out history to file, excluding lines that match `$HISTORY_IGNORE`.
  fc -W

  # Dispose of the current history and read the new history from file.
  fc -p $HISTFILE $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST

  # TA-DA!
  print -r "Deleted '$HISTORY_IGNORE' from history."
}
```

If you additionally want to prevent all `dc` commands from being written to history, add the following in your `~/.zshrc` file:

```bash
zshaddhistory() {
 [[ $1 != 'dc '* ]]
}
```

---

Alternatively, for a comprehensive, out-of-the-box solution, use my [Zsh Hist plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-hist).

Comment: This is the correct answer to the OP question

Answer (score 6):

1. Type and run at the zsh command line, open ~/.zsh_history (This opens TextEdit on my Mac.)
2. Delete any lines in the file
3. Save and close the file
4. Close/Exit the Zsh completely and restart the Zsh (this step is important!)
5. Now, open zsh and the history command does not show the lines that you deleted

Answer (score 5):

- read this for more info
  *https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-effectively-clear-your-bash-history/*

TL;DR

`cat /dev/null > ~/.zsh_history`

Answer (score 2):

E.g. with `vim` you can easily delete the last `n` lines like this:

1. Open file: `vim ~/.zsh_history`
2. Go to the bottom of the file: `G`
3. Mark lines: `V` -> move up with arrow key
4. Delete: `d`
5. Write & quit: `:wq`

Or you can just navigate with the cursor and delete any particular line with `dd`

Answer (score 2):

1. `fc -W` to write the history to the history file `$HISTFILE`.
2. Edit `$HISTFILE` with an editor of your choice or use in-place `sed` to replace the lines you don't like with something else or blank lines.
3. `fc -R` to read the history back from `$HISTFILE`.

Tips for the future:

- Set `setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` in your `.zshrc` file. With that option set, commands starting with a space won't end up in the history to begin with. Just prefix sensitive commands with a single space.
- Set `setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY` in your `.zshrc` file, then zsh will write new commands immediately to the history file. It's like calling `fc -W` before every new command but is more efficient (it won't write the entire history, just add a single line to the end of the file). That way the history file always reflects the current history and you can edit directly, then call `fc -R`. Note that you can then also call `fc -IR` at any time in other instances of zsh (e.g. another terminal) and immediately have the same history there available as well (nice way to easily sync history between instances).
- Alternatively you can enable `setopt SHARE_HISTORY`, which has the same effect as `INC_APPEND_HISTORY`, except that it also calls `fc -R` after every command, so basically there is no in-memory history, the history is always written to and read from file and that across all instances, so all zsh instances share exactly the same history at all times and editing the history file also edits the history of all zsh instances immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Open `.zsh_history` with your favourite editor and save keystrokes.

e.g. `subl .zsh_history` will open up history in Sublime editor and then delete whatever you want.
You can use TextEdit or other editors also.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
`LC_ALL=C sed -i '' '/line/d' $HISTFILE`

Replace "line" with what you want deleted.

From this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13661794/revisions

Comment: When you do not want the complete line to be deleted, you can also do: `sed -i 's/secret/#####/g' ~/.zsh_history`, which replaces the word `secret` by `######`  (also in this last line you type to remove the `secret` from your history file!)

Answer (score 0):

For ZSH

To locate the history file do :

```
echo $HISTFILE
```

- Then simply edit the file and remove any lines you wish to be gone as you would with `history -d id`.
- Save the file.
- Open a new terminal and you should see that there is nothing to see anymore !

---

However I am amazed that `history -d` does not exists. If it does exists it's well hidden.

Comment: In zsh, `history` is just an alias for `fc -l` and `fc -l -d` does not delete anything, `-d` means `print date timstamps`. `history -d` is bashism.

Comment: @Mecki My man fc(1) doesn't even show -d option. I wonder if a zsh plugin exists to fix this.