# sed substitution with Bash variables

Tags: bash, sed, substitution

I am trying to change the values in a text file using sed in a Bash script with the line,

```
sed 's/draw($prev_number;n_)/draw($number;n_)/g' file.txt > tmp
```

This will be in a `for` loop. Why is it not working?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Variables inside `'` don't get substituted in Bash. To get string substitution (or interpolation, if you're familiar with Perl) you would need to change it to use double quotes `"` instead of the single quotes:

```
# Enclose the entire expression in double quotes
$ sed "s/draw($prev_number;n_)/draw($number;n_)/g" file.txt > tmp

# Or, concatenate strings with only variables inside double quotes
# This would restrict expansion to the relevant portion
# and prevent accidental expansion for !, backticks, etc.
$ sed 's/draw('"$prev_number"';n_)/draw('"$number"';n_)/g' file.txt > tmp

# A variable cannot contain arbitrary characters
# See link in the further reading section for details
$ a='foo
bar'
$ echo 'baz' | sed 's/baz/'"$a"'/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
```

**Further Reading:**

- [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)
- [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)
- [Using different delimiters for sed substitute command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace)
- Unless you need it in a different file you can use the [-i flag to change the file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux)

Comment: Maybe also mention that if the variable contains slashes, you need to use a different delimiter which doesn't occur in the string (or backslash-escape every occurrence of the delimiter).  The slash is a common default for `s` but you can use any punctuation character; `sed "s%draw($prev_number;n_)%draw($number;n_)%g" file.txt` or `s#from#to#g` or `s_from_to_g` etc.

Comment: it doesn't work if the variable contains new-lines ("\n")

Comment: but it did once escaped (for my use cases) also slashes: `changelogEscaped=$(sed -e 's%\/%\\/%g; $!a\'$'\n''\\n' <<<"$changelog" | tr -d '\n')` Thanks for the link above.

Answer (score 17):

Variables within single quotes are not expanded, but within double quotes they are. Use double quotes in this case.

```
sed "s/draw($prev_number;n_)/draw($number;n_)/g" file.txt > tmp
```

You could also make it work with `eval`, but don’t do that!!

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Would you mind explaining what you mean by expanded?  My intuition tells me that it should be something like, variable substituted.  Also why not use eval?

Answer (score 4):

This may help:

```
sed "s/draw($prev_number;n_)/draw($number;n_)/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables like below. Like here, I wanted to replace `hostname` i.e., a system variable in the file. I am looking for string `look.me` and replacing that whole line with `look.me=<system_name>`

```
sed -i "s/.*look.me.*/look.me=`hostname`/"
```

You can also store your system value in another variable and can use that variable for substitution.

`host_var=``hostname`

`sed -i "s/.*look.me.*/look.me=$host_var/"`

---

Input file:

```
look.me=demonic
```

Output of file (assuming my system name is `prod-cfm-frontend-1-usa-central-1`):

```
look.me=prod-cfm-frontend-1-usa-central-1
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to input github tags from my release within github actions. So that on release it will automatically package up and push code to artifactory.

Here is how I did it. :)

```
  - name: Invoke build
    run: |
      # Gets the Tag number from the release
      TAGNUMBER=$(echo $GITHUB_REF | cut -d / -f 3)
      
      # Setups a string to be used by sed
      FINDANDREPLACE='s/${GITHUBACTIONSTAG}/'$(echo $TAGNUMBER)/
      
      # Updates the setup.cfg file within version number
      sed -i $FINDANDREPLACE setup.cfg
      
      # Installs prerequisites and pushes 
      pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
      invoke build
```

Retrospectively I wish I did this in python with tests. However it was fun todo some bash.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant, using `printf`:

```
SED_EXPR="$(printf -- 's/draw(%s;n_)/draw(%s;n_)/g' $prev_number $number)"

sed "${SED_EXPR}" file.txt
```

or in one line:

```
sed "$(printf -- 's/draw(%s;n_)/draw(%s;n_)/g' $prev_number $number)" file.txt
```

Using `printf` to build the replacement expression should be safe against all kinds of weird things, which is why I like this variant.