# Quoting bash 'sed' commands within python functions

Tags: python, bash, quoting

I'm using a build based on python.
I can define python functions like

```
do_install () { ... }
```

I can run bash commands within these functions, like

```
do_install () {
      sed '' ...
}
```

I am running a sed command in one of these functions

```
 sed -ri 's/PREFIX=/PREFIX=.../'
```

Within the quotes I need to use a global python variable, say. `${VARIABLE}`, like

```
sed -ri 's/PREFIX/PREFIX=${VARIABLE}/'
```

How do I quote the variable to be identified as a python global variable.  I tried a number of things including, using different string quoting in `sed`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using Python? `do_install () { ... }` is not a valid python function declaration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed substitution with bash variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables)

Comment: Im quite sure this has nothing to do wth python...

Comment: `sed -ri "s/PREFIX/PREFIX=${VARIABLE}/"` and where is Python?

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes `"` instead of simple.

By the way the code that you are posting is a simple bash script it has nothing of python.