# Unix sed command is not replacing the supplied string

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am writing a shell script in which I have to separate the file name and file path from a complete file path.  For example `/home/loneranger/Documents/test/file.dat` is the complete path. I want to separate name and Path and put them in variables.   So far I am able to separate file name by using basename command.

```
file_name =$(basename $path) 
file_location =`echo $path | sed 's/$file_name//' `
```

But the sed command is not working.  It's working when I execute it outside in command line by replacing the file_name by file.dat.   Not sure why it's behaving this way.   Can somebody explain.

PS: Sorry for poor formatting as I am typing from a mobile device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed substitution with bash variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables)

Answer (score 4):

the tool `dirname` does what you want:

```
file_name=$(basename $path)
file_location=$(dirname $path)
```

the sed command is not working because bash does not expand variables inside single quotes.

```
sed 's/$file_name//'
    ^ single quote
       ^ variable inside single quote not expanded
```

either use double quotes or open the single quotes around the variable:

```
sed "s/$file_name//"
sed 's/'$file_name'//'
```

but as said the tool `dirname` does what you want.

also note that you may not put spaces around the equal sign in the variable assignment

```
file_name =$(basename $path)
         ^ there should be no space here
```

the line above does not assign the result of `basename` to the variable `file_name`. instead it will try to execute the command `file_name` with one parameter which is the result of `basename`.

```
file_name=$(basename $path)
         ^ no space here
```

this line will define the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because you use `$file_name` in simple quote (`'`). Use double quotes `"` for enable variable translation.

```
file_location =`echo $path | sed "s/$file_name//"
```