# Use variable inside double quotes inside single quotes in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to search for a string enclosed in double quotes given by a positional parameter. This is what I've done:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    FOO=$0

    sed -i 's/"${FOO}"/bar/m' file.txt
```

Neither `"$FOO"` nor `\"a${FOO}\"/` work.

I am aware that for variables to be expanded, you have to enclose the whole regex in double quotes ([sed substitution with bash variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables)). The thing is that the string I am searching for is also enclosed in double quotes, that is why I enclosed the whole regex in single quotes. I also tried to enclose it in double quotes and escaping the double quotes, but it didn't work.

An explanation of the logic behind single and double quotes escaping would be really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes to quote the sed commands as

`sed -i "s/\"${FOO}\"/bar/m" file.txt`

Test:

```
$ echo $b
hello
$ echo \"hello\" | sed "s/\"$b\"/asdf/"
asdf
```

Comment: Will this match "foo" (including the quotes) if the positional parameter is "foo" (without the quotes)?

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you

Comment: I want to search for: "blaba", not blabla. I expect that the string passed to the script will not be enclosed in double quotes, but the text that I have to find is.

Comment: @Federico i have edited the answer to include that as well. Hope it helps now

Comment: Hmm. It's not working. Now the command output throws an error `sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unknown option to `s'`

Comment: @Federico check the edit. I have added an example to make it clear