# Replace entire line with bash variable using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to use sed to replace the entire line at a match with a bash variable. Replacing with plain text is fine.

```
$ echo -e "foo bar\nfooy bary\nfoot bart" | sed '/fooy/c\text'
foo bar
text
foot bart
```

If the text I want to replace with is stored in a bash variable, however, this does not work.

```
$ var="This is poetry."
$ echo -e "foo bar\nfooy bary\nfoot bart" | sed "/fooy/c\$var"
foo bar
$var
foot bart
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Remove the `\ ` It escapes the meaning of `$`

Comment: Thanks. I got confused by all the examples I found, always using `c\ ` and not just `c`. Thought it was syntax.

Comment: If you would have researched a bit could have found the answer already. There are many such questions in SO for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables. Anyways all the best !!

Comment: The question is a bit different in my opinion, since I want to change the entire line and not use `sed "s/foo/bar/"` to only replace `foo` with `bar`.

Comment: Yeah I agree that it is different . But it clearly shows how you should be using bash variables in `sed`, since it was where you got stuck at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this with sed (which you shouldn't, see below), use

```
sed "/fooy/c\\$var"
```

This is a shell expansion problem. `\$` in a doubly quoted string means a literal dollar, so `$var` is not expanded. GNU sed also accepts

```
sed "/fooy/c$var"
```

as long as you don't specify `--posix`, but BSD sed (as you may have on FreeBSD or MacOS X) will complain about it.

However, doing this with sed is not a good idea. Substituting shell variables into sed code is almost never a good idea, because it makes you vulnerable to code injection. Take, for example,

```
$ var=$(echo -e 'something\nd')
$ echo -e "foo bar\nfooy bary\nfoot bart" | sed --posix "/fooy/c\\$var"
something
```

That wasn't what we expected, was it? What happens here is that `sed`, since it is unable do distinguish what you want it to treat as data (`$var`) and code, treats `$var` as code, and therefore it treats the `d` after the `\n` in it as a command (to delete the current line). A better way is to use `awk`:

```
$ var=$(echo -e 'something\nd')
$ echo -e "foo bar\nfooy bary\nfoot bart" | awk -v var="$var" '/fooy/ { print var; next } 1'
foo bar
something
d
foot bart
```

This sidesteps the code injection issue by not treating `$var` as code.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough explanation. I was not aware of the `'/pattern/ {...}'` syntax in `awk`. Will definitely start using that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't escape the `$` symbol. In bash, variables are referred by `$variable-name`. If you do escaping the `$` symbol, then the bash won't consider it as a variable. It would treat `$var` as literal `$var` .

```
$ echo -e "foo bar\nfooy bary\nfoot bart" | sed "/fooy/c$var"
foo bar
This is poetry.
foot bart
```