# shell :How to use UDV in this Grep structure without having issues?

Tags: bash, shell, variable-expansion

I have an assigment that asks me to print on screen the number of words that are longer than a given number ,let's say k , which is read from the keyboard. and then to order the result. 
Until now I decided to try in this way :

```
#!bin/bash
k=0
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then 
    echo "No argument supplied."
    exit 1
fi
echo -n "Give the minimal lenght of the words : "
read k 
for files in "$@"
do
    if [ -f "$files" ]; then
        echo "$(cat $files | egrep -o '[^ ]{k,}' $files | wc -w) : $files."
    else
        echo "Error: File $files has not been found."
    fi
done | sort -n
```

My issues is that whenever I try this program with k in the section "egrep -o '[^ ]{k,}'" it always gives a wrong answer. But if I replaced it with an integer, in works exactly as I wanted. 
Which is the right way to make this code work for k read from keyboard? which is the syntax , can't really understand how I should write there , tried other ways to like "$k" , $k , ((k)) , `k`.
Any help is welcome , a hint if someone could give me please? I am stuck

Comment: While this is a different command the concept of the question is the same "how do I use shell variables in a string part of a command I am running" so the answer is still the correct one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables

Comment: As an additional point `echo $(command)` is almost **never** at all useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
echo "$(egrep -o '[^ ]{'"$k"',}' "$files" | wc -w): $files"
```

- Your immediate problem was using `k` instead of `$k`.

  - To refer to a variable in Bash, you must prefix its name with `$` (by contrast, you mustn't use `$` when *assigning* to it). In some cases, to separate the variable name from subsequent tokens, you must enclose the name in `{..}`, e.g., `${k}`, which you may also opt to do for visual clarity, even when it's not strictly required.
- Your next problem was using *single* quotes to delimit the `egrep` search regex (inside the command substitution), which prevents expansion of variable references.

  - Note that even though you were using a double-quoted string *overall*, embedded command substitutions (`$(...)`) are their own worlds, in which the usual parsing rules apply (single-quoted strings are literals, whereas double-quoted strings may have embedded variable references, command substitutions, arithmetic expansions).
- However, simply using *double* quotes instead - inside which variable references *are* expanded - would *potentially* *not* fix the problem *in this case*, **due to a bug in bash 3.2.57** related to [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) (`{...}`) inside a command substitution:

  - This bug is no longer present in bash 4.3.30 (don't know when it was fixed), so there you *could* use a single, double-quoted string: `"[^ ]{$k,}"`. However, the solution presented works in both bash 3.x and 4.x
  - Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the bug in bash 3.2.57:

    - `k=3; echo "$(egrep -co "[^ ]{$k,}" <<<$'abc\nde')"`
    - This *should* return `1`, but returns `0 2`, due to mistakenly applying brace expansion to `{3,}` (resulting in *two* strings: `egrep -co '[^ ]3'` and `egrep -co '[^ ]'`), even though it is contained inside a double-quoted string.
- Thus, the answer is to ***splice in* the variable reference between two *single*-quoted strings**:

  - `'[^ ]{'"$k"',}'` concatenates literal `[^ ]{` with the value of variable `$k` and literal `,}`. If `$k` is `4`, for instance, `egrep` then sees the following string: `[^ ]{4,}`
- (Also, the initial `cat $files |` was unnecessary, since the file is also passed as an *operand* (non-option argument), and you should always double-quote variables containing filenames, so the command won't break with filenames with embedded spaces.)
- Finally, I suggest renaming `$files` to `$file` to avoid confusion: in each iteration of the loop, you're only dealing with a *single* file.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the fast answer and also thanks a lot for the detailed explanation it helped me to understand the though procces :). First of all yes cat was an extra I didn't have to use it , was my reflex to write in from the labs where I wrote only 1 line comands .Then about the egrep -co I might have an issue. I've tried also egrep -co before posting this question , and whne I used it it would return only the number of lines that had a word that was longer than my k.I use this longer version with wc in order to count all words. And also using 4.3.3 and your other solution words.thx :)

Comment: @Wiuwi: My pleasure; sorry that I messed up the `egrep -co` part - it's fixed now.