# Using sed to append multiple lines (with shell variables) after match

Tags: bash, sed, posix

Not GNU sed. I have a collection of makefiles I'm trying to uniformly modify. In each makefile, I have a comment that tells me where to put the code.

```
sed "/MULTI WORD COMMENT/a\
LINE 1\
LINE 2 $stuff $morestuff" "$file" >> "$file"_NEW
```

I want to find the comment, then append multiple lines of text after it. Some lines contain shell variables I want to expand. All I could figure out is that I need to use `"` when I want to do [shell expansions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680548/5136812) and that each line to be appended should get its own line.

I get an error telling me to terminate the "a" command with "\", but it looks like I'm already doing that. What am I doing wrong?

Example input

```
# MULTI WORD COMMENT
.SUFFIXES: .o .c
```

Example output

```
# MULTI WORD COMMENT
LINE 1
LINE 2 ASDF GASIFJ
.SUFFIXES: .o .c
```

In this case, `stuff=ASDF` and `morestuff=GASIFJ`. These are not entirely unlike the variable names in the makefiles I'm working with.

Comment: Show sample input and your desired output for that sample input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using double quotes you need to escape twice, so use:

```
sed "/MULTI LINE COMMENT/a\\
LINE 1\\
LINE 2 $stuff $morestuff" "$file" >> "$file"_NEW
```

**PS:** Your example input has `MULTI LINE COMMENT` but your command has `MULTI WORD COMMENT`

Comment: Note that if either `$stuff` or `$morestuff` itself contains newlines, there are still problems.  The OP might then do better to put the extra information into a file and use `r` to read the extra information from its file at the correct point in the main input file.

Comment: Yes I agree with that. `$stuff` and `$morestuff` should be simple strings without newlines here.

Comment: Fixed comment example. Luckily, those variables are just names of modules, so no newlines in them. Script is working now, thank you.