# A shell script to to change a value in a file with a parameter

Tags: shell, sh, informatica-powercenter

I am an etl developer, am very new to shell scripting,

My file is param.prm

```
[3_go:wf_test:s_test]

$Dbconnection=abcd

$Dbstring=qwert
```

I need a shell script to to read the above file and change the value of $dbconnection (now abcd) dynamically with the variable I pass , every time I run the script. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed substitution with bash variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/\($Dbconnection=\).*/\1NewValue/' param.prm 
[3_go:wf_test:s_test]

$Dbconnection=NewValue

$Dbstring=qwert
```

To change the file in-place, use the `-i` option.  For GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/\($Dbconnection=\).*/\1NewValue/' param.prm
```

For BSD (OSX) sed:

```
sed -i "" 's/\($Dbconnection=\).*/\1NewValue/' param.prm
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply.....the first line in the file is [3_go:wf_test:s_test]...so will this comand skip this line go to second line?....thank you

Comment: @user2722449 The current version will leave that line unchanged.  Did you want it removed?