# Update file using linux sed command

Tags: linux, shell, sed

The requirement is simple, but since I am not a linux expert and the available code from stackoverflow is not working, I need help.
I have a parameter file for Information, in a specific row I have the below pattern:

```
$$REFRESH_LOAD_TIME=200
```

I need a shell script to update the 200 to a new value that is passed as an argument to the shell script. Below code is not working as expected.

```
#!/bin/bash
RefreshUTCDateTime="$1"
ParameterFileLocation ="$2"
sed -i 's/$$REFRESH_LOAD_TIME/$$REFRESH_LOAD_TIME=$RefreshUTCDateTime /g' $ParameterFileLocation*
```

Expected value **post execution,** when **100** is passed as an argument.

```
$$REFRESH_LOAD_TIME=100
```

I want through this [A shell script to to change a value in a file with a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664080/a-shell-script-to-to-change-a-value-in-a-file-with-a-parameter) 
But it is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/\$\$REFRESH_LOAD_TIME.*/\$\$REFRESH_LOAD_TIME=$RefreshUTCDateTime /g" $ParameterFileLocation*
```

Brief explanation,

- Variable expansion happens in double quotes.
- And the dollar sign need to be escaped in `sed` for pattern substitution.