# Using SED within a shell to replace pattern in desired files

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a bash shell script written as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#arg1: pattern to be found
#arg2: pattern to be replaced
#arg3: filename pattern
echo replace $1 by $2 for all $3 files
for  i in `find . -type f -name "$3"`
do
sed  's/$1/$2/g' $i
done
```

I use this script (say, called SUBS) as:

```
./SUBS bbb ddd aa
```

where the file aa has:

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

But, while I expect to see bbbb replaced as dddb, it shows the same content i.e. bbbb.
Any clue what is wrong here?
Also, I would like to make the same file getting modified after the replacement. How can I do that?
This Qs is little similar to [sed substitution with bash variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables), but in my Qs, I have used a pattern to find and replace as argument to the shell variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables won't expand when put inside single quotes; you need to use double quotes:

```
sed "s/$1/$2/g" "$i"
```

---

To modify the file in place:

```
sed -i.bak "s/$1/$2/g" "$i"
```

After the operation the original file will be backed up with `.bak` extension; if you don't want to keep backup:

```
sed -i "s/$1/$2/g" "$i"
```

Comment: Many thanks.  I would like to make the same file getting modified after the replacement. How can I do that? It's displaying on stdout now

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana Check my edits..

Comment: I am using Solaris, where sed -i is not supported, any other option?

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana I don't have Solaris so can't tell..although you can use redirection: `sed "s/$1/$2/g" "$i" >"$i".bak && mv "$i".bak "$i"`

Comment: That's nice, this would do