# Find variable pattern match and delete line by sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have a variable pattern. And I want to match pattern in file and if pattern is matched then line should be deleted.

I tried with:

```
sed '/$pattern/d' file.txt
```

But it doesn't work.

Please give me guidence for the same.

Thanks.

Comment: use double quotes: `sed "/$pattern/d" file.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed substitution with bash variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables)

Answer (score 2):

Just do that:

```
sed /$pattern/d file.txt
```

The quotes were transforming your variable in a string. Then you need to remove that.

And if you need to to write the changes in the file, just add `-i`

```
sed -i /$pattern/d file.txt
```