# Adding Isolate CPU Cores in /etc/default/grub using sed

Tags: shell

I want to add commands to the file /etc/default/grub by using sed.

```
REPLACE="intel_idle.max_cstate=0 isolcpus=2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22     nohz_full=2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 rcu_nocbs=2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22"

sed -i 's/[A-Za-z0-9]*GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=[A-Za-z0-9]*/ $REPLACE/g'   /etc/default/grub
```

But it does not work.
Any ideas ?¨

Comment: Single quotes prevent parameter expansion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed substitution with bash variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables)