# Replace string and include date inside all .html files within a directory

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am looking for bash code to replace all `<title>XXX</title>` within all **.html** files to `<title>XXX - YYY $Date</title>`

What I came up with, using **sed** is:

```
sed -i "s/</title>/ - YYY 'date'/g" /home/mirror/*
```

This however, doesn't implement the .html requirement and I can't get it to work, I'm either getting

```
sed: no imput files
```

or

```
-bash: s/</title>/ - YYY 'date'/g: No such file or directory
```

The structure is:

```
/home/mirror/
├── images
├── archive
│   └── index.html
│   └── 2.html
├── index.html
├── 2.html
├── style.css
└── scripts.js
```

How can I do this?

Comment: see also 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables 3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string/1585810

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `find` to recurse through the directories:

```
find /home/mirror -name '*.html' -exec sed -i "s@</title>@ - YYY $Date</title>@g" {} +
```

Note I replaced "'date'" with "$Date" as that's what you said you wanted to add.  I also use `@` instead of `/` as the `sed s` separator character, to avoid interference from the `</title>` parts.

Comment: thank you, this worked exactly as I needed & I learned a little bit more today. have a nice day John Zwinck :)