# sh script to replace text in multiple files

Tags: shell, unix, sed, scripting, sh

I am trying to replace every occurrence in a .prm file of the string "/net/origin/devdata1/slin" with "/tools/common/test/HATS" in over a hundred files using sed. I think I am having trouble with the proper syntax for a for loop that loops through different files in a directory(/home/AutoTest), and what/if I need as command line arguments. Thanks in advance.

```
OLD="/net/origin/devdata1/slin" 
NEW="/toolscommon/test/HATS" 
DIR="/home/AutoTest" 
for f in $DIR 
do 
    cp $f $f.bak 
   sed 's+$OLD+$NEW+g' $f.bak &gt; $f 
   [ -f "$f" ] 
   rm -f $f.bak 
done
```

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many people don't like that.

Comment: Of course. Here is what I tried (very amateur since I'm not a pro at sh scripting)

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Also, what OS are you using?  Linux, OSX, other?

Comment: I'm using Unix @John1024

Comment: Is `[ -f "$f" ]` intended to do something?  Currently, it evaluates whether the file exists but has no affect on the script.  Perhaps you intended to write `[ -f "$f" ] && rm -f $f.bak`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed substitution with bash variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables)

Comment: I generally find these sort of things easier with a shell command one-liner using `find`... something along the lines of `find . -name \*.prm -exec sed -i '.bak' 'whatever sed commands' {} +` ... rather than writing a script that has to do the looping itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using sed

Try:

```
old="/net/origin/devdata1/slin"
new="/toolscommon/test/HATS"
dir="/home/AutoTest"
sed -i "s+$old+$new+g" "$dir"/*
```

`sed -i` will update files in-place.

Also, it is best practices to use lower or mixed case names for your shell variables.  The system uses all-caps names for its variables and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.

There is a potential danger here if `old` or `new` contained any sed-active characters.  If so, arbitrary files could be deleted or mangled.

#### Using awk

```
old="/net/origin/devdata1/slin"
new="/toolscommon/test/HATS"
dir="/home/AutoTest"
awk -i inplace -v old="$old" -v new="$new" '{gsub(old, new)} 1' "$dir"/*
```

Because awk treats `old` and `new` as data and not code, this is safer than the sed version.