# Replace a line with a matching pattern using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to replace this line

```
command: [ "--no-save", "--no-restore", "--slave", "/home/app/src/work-daily.py", "20180212"]
```

with

```
command: [ "--no-save", "--no-restore", "--slave", "/home/app/src/work-daily.py", "20180305"]
```

`20180305` is today's date where I am storing its value in a variable dated

My approach is

```
sed 's/.*command.*/"command: \[ "--no-save", "--no-restore", "--slave", "/home/app/src/work-daily.py", "$dated"\]"/' ghj.txt
```

where

```
dated=$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

its giving an error similar to this

> sed: -e expression #1, char 81: unknown option to `s'

Comment: single-quotes don't expand variables! and change the separator from `/` to any other one `|` or `#`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace ... also, you are better off trying to simplify the command... like `/^command/ s/<match at end>/<replace>/`

Answer (score 1):

Your command can be made to work with some change in the quoting and escaping:

```
$ sed 's/.*command.*/command: \[ "--no-save", "--no-restore", "--slave", "\/home\/app\/src\/work-daily.py", "'"$dated"'"\]/' ghj.txt
command: [ "--no-save", "--no-restore", "--slave", "/home/app/src/work-daily.py", "20180305"]
```

It looks like you only want to change the last field on lines that include the string `command:`.  In that case, the sed command can simplify to:

```
$ sed -E "/command:/ s/\"[[:digit:]]+\"\]/\"$dated\"]/" ghj.txt
command: [ "--no-save", "--no-restore", "--slave", "/home/app/src/work-daily.py", "20180305"]
```

Alternatively, using awk:

```
$ awk -F\" -v d="$dated" '/command:/{$10=d} 1' OFS=\" ghj.txt
command: [ "--no-save", "--no-restore", "--slave", "/home/app/src/work-daily.py", "20180305"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend **awk** for this task

You can substitute the last field in real time by calling `date` within `awk`

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'BEGIN{"date +%Y%m%d" | getline d} {$NF=" \""d"\"]"}1' file
command: [ "--no-save", "--no-restore", "--slave", "/home/app/src/work-daily.py", "20180305"]
```

`"date +%Y%m%d" | getline d;`  : Date would get store in `d`

`$NF=" \""d"\"]"` : Replacing last field with format `"date"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `sed` command:

```
$ cat input; dated=$(date +%Y%m%d); sed "/.*command: \[ \"--no-save\", \"--no-restore\", \"--slave\", \".*work-daily.py\", \"20180212\"\]/s/201
80212/$dated/" input                                                                                                                         
command: [ "--no-save", "--no-restore", "--slave", "/home/app/src/work-daily.py", "20180212"]
command: [ "--no-save", "--no-restore", "--slave", "/home/app/src/work-daily.py", "20180305"]
```

where `/.*command: \[ \"--no-save\", \"--no-restore\", \"--slave\", \".*work-daily.py\", \"20180212\"\]/` is used to find the proper line in the file and `s/20180212/$dated/` is used to do the replacement.