# SED command interpretation

Tags: shell, sed

I came across the below `sed` statement in our shell script.

`sed -n "/set -A $REC/,/#${REC}_END/p"`

I know that `-n` option suppresses the automatic printing and `p` is to display.

Are the contents inside `/../` a plain string or another command is being used in the above statement? (`set -A`)

Comment: it is just string.. however, the double quotes allow variable substitution (shell functionality, nothing to do with sed).. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables (one of the links from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info)

Comment: @Sundeep So the meaning of the above statement is making a string which starts with `set -A $REC` and ends with `#${REC}_END` ?

Comment: no, it is address range.. see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an "address range", it tells sed to only print lines between `/set -A $REC/` and `/#${REC}_END/`. Double quotes around the expression expand variables, so $REC will be replaced by the variable value (hopefully, it doesn'
t contain a slash) in the first address, and similarly `${REC}` in the second one. The curly brackets are needed there, as an underscore is a valid part of a variable name, so `$REC_END` looks like a variable name, not a variable name followed by a string `_END`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what is "address range"?

Comment: It limits the following command only to the given lines. See `man sed` for details.