# Unable to replace string using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a bash script that loops over a set of files, and replaces a string, in each file, with a version number.

```
#!/bin/bash

ANGULAR_APP_VERSION=6.6.6
echo $ANGULAR_APP_VERSION

declare -a arr=(
"test1.txt" 
"test2.txt"
)

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
  sed 's/"@@BUILD_VERSION@@"/"'$ANGULAR_APP_VERSION'"/g' ${arr[$i]}
done
```

Everytime I run the script, it generates the following error:

```
./test1.txt: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "./test1.txt")
```

I don't understand why it is wrong. The files exist.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables which is one of the faqs listed in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

ANGULAR_APP_VERSION="6.6.6"
echo "$ANGULAR_APP_VERSION"

arr=(
    "test1.txt" 
    "test2.txt"
)

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
     sed -i "s/@@BUILD_VERSION@@/$ANGULAR_APP_VERSION/g" "$i"
done
```

(`$i` is each value of the array one at a time in the iteration)

or using array `key` :

```
for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
     sed -i "s/@@BUILD_VERSION@@/$ANGULAR_APP_VERSION/g" "${arr[i]}"
done
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
>   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: Using: sed "s/@@BUILD_VERSION@@/$ANGULAR_APP_VERSION/g" "$i" works, but it doesn't update the files, it just prints out the modified sring

using: sed "s/@@BUILD_VERSION@@/$ANGULAR_APP_VERSION/g" "${arr[i]}" generates the following: test1.txt: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".txt")

Comment: For sure, you never asked to. Just add `-i` switch. Post edited accordingly

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I will accept this answer in 5 minutes, when it allows me to.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that not every implementation of `sed` supports `-i` or supports it with no arguments