# SED - replace string newline anything with string newline varable

Tags: sed

I have the following content in a file

```
  dhcp_option_domain:
  - test.domain
```

And what I need to do is this:

whenever the value 'dhcp_option_domain:' followed by a newline and then ANY string, replace it with 'dhcp_option_domain:' followed by a newline and a variable.

ie if I set a variable of dhcp_domain="different.com" then then string above would convert to:

```
  dhcp_option_domain:
  - different.com
```

Note that both lines have and need to maintain leading 2 spaces.

I do not want to just do a search and replace on 'test.domain' as I have a few cases to use this and the values could be different each time the sed command is run.

I have tried a few methods such as:

```
dhcp_domain="something.com"
sed -i 's|dhcp_option_domain:\n.*|dhcp_option_domain:\n  - $dhcp_domain|g' filename
```

however cannot get it to work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `sed` works line by line (using newline character to distinguish newlines)

```
$ cat ip.txt
foo baz
  dhcp_option_domain:
  - test.domain
123
  dhcp_option_domain:
$ dhcp_domain='something.com'
$ sed '/^  dhcp_option_domain:/{n; s/.*/  - '"$dhcp_domain"'/}' ip.txt
foo baz
  dhcp_option_domain:
  - something.com
123
  dhcp_option_domain:
```

- `/^  dhcp_option_domain:/` condition to match

  - `{}` to group more than one command to be executed when this condition is satisfied
- `n` get next line
- `s/.*/  - '"$dhcp_domain"'/` replace it as required - note that shell variables won't be expanded inside single quotes, see [sed substitution with bash variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables)
   for details
- note that last line in the file didn't trigger the change as there was no further line
- tested on GNU sed, syntax might vary for other implementations

From [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands)

> n
>
> If auto-print is not disabled, print the pattern space, then,
>   regardless, replace the pattern space with the next line of input. If
>   there is no more input then sed exits without processing any more
>   commands.

Comment: thanks that works perfectly on CentOS7.5  AND I don't need to requote the first string (dhcp_option_domain:) which is what I have been doing previously.  What part of the code reuses or preserves the first string? You also answered my question within 30 mins which is astounding!

Comment: check the quoted text from manual at end of answer... `If auto-print is not disabled, print the pattern space`.. in this case, on seeing `n`, sed will print the `dhcp_option_domain` line as is, and we will have only the next line to work with.. on GNU sed, using `N` instead of `n` will give you both lines to work with.. see [my tutorial](https://github.com/learnbyexample/Command-line-text-processing/blob/master/gnu_sed.md#n-and-n-commands) if you need more examples to understand..

Answer (score 2):

As [the manual explains](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Execution-Cycle):

> `sed` operates by performing the following cycle on each line of input: first, sed reads one line from the input stream, removes any trailing newline, and places it in the pattern space. Then commands are executed

Your regex (`dhcp_option_domain:\n.*`) does not match because there is no `\n` in the pattern space in the first place.

A possible solution:

```
sed '/dhcp_option_domain:$/{n;c\
  - '"$dhcp_domain"'
}'
```

The `/dhcp_option_domain:$/` part is [an address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses-overview). The following command is only executed on lines matching that pattern.

The `{` `}` command groups multiple commands into a single block.

The `n` command prints out the current pattern space and replaces it by the next line of input.

The `c\` command replaces the current pattern space by whatever follows in the script. Here it gets a bit tricky. We have:

- a literal newline in the sed program (required after `c\`), then
- `-`  (placing those characters in the pattern space literally, then
- `'` (part of shell syntax, terminating the single-quoted part started by `sed '...`), then
- `"` (starting a double-quoted part), then
- `$dhcp_domain` (which, because it's in a double-quoted part, interpolates the contents of the `dhcp_domain` shell variable), then
- `"` (terminating the double-quoted part), then
- `'` (starting another single-quoted part), then
- a literal newline again (terminating the text after `c\`), then
- `}` (closing the block started by `{`).

Comment: Sed has an `-e` option, which adds a newline to `a`, `i`, `r`, `R`, `w`, `W` and `c` commands, so `sed -e '/dhcp_option_domain:$/{n;c\  - '"${var}" -e '}'` would work too. Another way to step around this problem is to negate the search e.g. `sed  ' /dhcp_option_domain:$/!b;n;c\  -'"${var}"`

Comment: @potong The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) said "*As a GNU extension, the c command and text can be separated into two -e parameters, enabling easier scripting*" and I wanted to keep it portable.

Comment: I am probably wrong, but I have a feeling that the *new* GNU manual errs on the side of caution. The `-e` option is not GNU specific (see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html)) and I believe it has always had this property. However I only use GNU sed and cannot verify this.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/dhcp_option_domain:$/{p;s//  - '"${var}"'/;n;d}' file
```

Match on `dhcp_option_domain:`, print it, substitute the new domain name (maintaining indent), print the current line and fetch the next (`n`) and delete it.