# I want to use sed commands with variables , while giving the value of variable in runtime

Tags: variables, unix, sed, devops

```
#!/bin/bash

Read a
Read b
Sed -i 's/$a/$b/' txt.txt
```

I have also use double quotes but it is not working

Comment: *I have also use double quotes but it is not working* - Please show a test case.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: you also have to ensure that the values in those variables do not conflict with delimiter and you might have to escape metacharacters depending on your use case.. see the answer and links in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables