# Edit to line with sed printing the new line twice

Tags: unix, sed

I have this **settings** in SSH configs (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`)

```
AllowUsers root john
```

I want to add `jane` to the end of the line

```
AllowUsers root john jane
```

I've tried

```
sed -i -e '/AllowUsers/{s/:/ /g;s/.*=//;s/$/ jane/p}' /etc/ssh/sshd_config && cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

I kept getting this result

```
AllowUsers root john jane 
AllowUsers root john jane
```

Why does extra line come?

---

## Note

If I somehow run that command twice

I will get these result

```
AllowUsers root john jane 
AllowUsers root john jane 
AllowUsers root john jane 
AllowUsers root john jane
```

run it again x3 times, will get me this

```
AllowUsers root john jane 
AllowUsers root john jane 
AllowUsers root john jane 
AllowUsers root john jane 
AllowUsers root john jane 
AllowUsers root john jane 
AllowUsers root john jane 
AllowUsers root john jane 
AllowUsers root john jane 
AllowUsers root john jane
```

Comment: (Speaking to original title and tagging:) This is not meaningfully a bash question -- `sed` is not a feature of bash, a part of bash, distributed or versioned with bash, etc; the same behavior would happen if sed were, say, started from Python with `shell=False`, from C via an `execv`-family syscall, etc.

Comment: `sed '/^AllowUsers[[:blank:]]/s/$/ jane/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `p` flag in `s/$/ jane/p` will print the pattern space. Then pattern space will be printed again when the cycle is ended, resulting in two lines. Remove the `p` flag.

That said, just:

```
sed 's/AllowUsers .*/& jane/'
```

Comment: Tried, and nothing seem added ! Did you test that command ?

Comment: `sed 's/AllowUsers .*/& jane/' <<<'AllowUsers root john'` outputs `AllowUsers root john jane`

Comment: Ok seems working now. What if I want to insert variable ? 

`sed 's/AllowUsers .*/& ${user}/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: Then you should become acquainted with the [difference between single and double quotes in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: @cyber8200 see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables for things you need to take care when using shell variables with sed