# sed -i ‘’ -e '/javaagent.jar/ s/$/ proxyPort=8080/' this command should append string only if the line is uncommented

Tags: shell, sed

Im using below to append proxyport=8080 to the end of the line where javaagent.jar string found and below is working fine, but this should ignore if there is a # (commented line) in the text file

```
sed -i '' -e '/javaagent.jar/ s/$/ proxyPort=8080/'
```

Example input:

```
#/opt/ver/inmind/javaagent.jar
/opt/ver/inmind/javaagent.jar
```

Example output should be:

```
#/opt/ver/inmind/javaagent.jar
/opt/ver/inmind/javaagent.jar proxyPort=8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a FreeBSD `sed` version (as you have `-i ''` in your command), you can use

```sh
sed -i '' -e '/^#/!s/javaagent\.jar.*/& proxyPort=8080/' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/YXgInL).

The `/^#/!` part stops processing lines starting with `#` (add `[[:space:]]*` after `^` to account for indentation, any leading whitespace), and if there is no `#` at the start, `s/javaagent\.jar.*/& proxyPort=8080/` finds `javaagent.jar` + the rest of the line and replaces this match with itself (with `&`) and adds a space and `proxyPort=8080`.

Comment: Thank you very much,  can I substitute variable instead of string proxyPort=8080

Comment: @ChandraShekharReddy see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables

Comment: @ChandraShekharReddy See [an example here](https://ideone.com/5Tch1m).