# Sed replace value in index.html by environment variable with slashes keeping enclosing text intact

Tags: html, bash, sed

I have the basic html, for example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script>window.API_URL = ''</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to replace '' by environment variable.
Env variable will contain slashes (for example: https://website.com/api

I'm trying to use the following code but it just outputted `$MY_API_URL` instead of real value and `</script>` text got removed:

```
cat index.html | sed -i -e '/window\.API_URL =/ s/= .*/= \"${MY_API_URL}\";/' index.html
```

Given `MY_API_URL=https://somesite.com`, I expect to get `<script>window.API_URL = "https://somesite.com";</script>`.

Comment: Actually, [sed substitution with Bash variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables) cannot be used as duplicate reason because it does not solve the current problem, namely, get `<script>window.API_URL = "<Link inside MY_API_URL variable>";</script>`, as the `</script>` part will be removed. OP needs to keep this part inside the result. I edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i 's/\(window\.API_URL =\)[^<]*/\1 "'"${MY_API_URL//\//\\\/}"'";/' index.html
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/nhIXSd).

*Details*:

- `\(window\.API_URL =\)[^<]*` - a POSIX BRE pattern that matches and captures into Group 1 `window.API_URL =` text and then matches any zero or more chars other than `<`
- `\1 "'"${MY_API_URL//\//\\\/}"'";` - a replacement that puts back the value captured into Group 1 (`\1`) and then adds a space, `"`, the `MY_API_URL` value and then `";` string.

The `${MY_API_URL//\//\\\/}` is an example of variable expansion where a `/` is replaced with `\/` (thanks to `//` after the variable name, all occurrences are replaced).

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor, you saved my day