# Bash script with multiple inputs and sed not working

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting

I have a file with elements a,b,c which I want to replace with proper values that I input in the terminal. I am making use of a .bashrc script named hi.sh.

I input the filename containing the elements a,b,c as a ifile and want to write it in a new file which I have defined as ofile.

The script I have prepared is:

```
#!/bin/bash

read date tm MJD ifile ofile
echo Enter date (DD/MM/YYYY) : $date
echo Enter IST - 5:30 HRS time: $tm
echo Enter MJD : $MJD
echo Enter input file with abc var(~/) : $ifile
echo Enter input output file : $ofile

do
sed -e 's/a/$date/g' -e 's/b/$tm/g' -e 's/c/$MJD/g' $ifile > $ofile
done
```

However on running bash hi.sh in the terminal, the script is not working.

What is the issue and solution for this? I am new to scripting with bashrc

Comment: Check your script with http://shellcheck.net

Comment: I think you mean "bash script", not ".bashrc script".

Comment: You need to quote `(DD/MM/YYYY)` because `()` has special meaning in the shell.

Comment: You need to put the `sed` arguments in double quotes, because variables aren't expanded inside single quotes.

Comment: I even gave you a link in your last question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables which explains the quoting problem.