# How to include variables in sed commands?

Tags: shell, sed

I have two different configuration files like following :

```
# Database
database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database_name
```

and

```
# API
api.port=5005
```

I would like to change both of them, by utilizing sed commands in a shell script.

---

##### What I have done & Problem :

This is the shell script that I made to accomplish it :

```bash
DB_CONFIG_FILE=~/configs/database.properties
MYSQL_CONTAINER_PORT=3113

sed -i 's~^database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database_name.*database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:${MYSQL_CONTAINER_PORT}/database_name~' $DB_CONFIG_FILE

TM_CONFIG_FILE=~/configs/tm.properties
PORT=5100

sed -i 's~^api.port=5005.*api.port=${PORT}~' $TM_CONFIG_FILE
```

However, that gave me an error saying :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char : unterminated `s' command
```

Is there a workaround to include those variables declared in the script?
Thank you

---

##### Expectation :

My expectation is to modify the configuration files to something like this :

```
# Database
database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3113/database_name
```

and

```
# API
api.port=5100
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sed substitution with Bash variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few reasons:

1. Your sed command is broken as there is no substitution after delimiter `~`
2. Shell variables won't expand in single quotes, use double quotes
3. RegEx meta characters such `.`, `*`. `?`, `+` need to be escaped in sed regex.

Following sed should work for you:

```bash
dbCfgFile=~/configs/database.properties
mysqlContainerPort=3113
sed -E -i.bak "s~^(database\.url=jdbc:mysql://127\.0\.0\.1)(/.*)~\1:$mysqlContainerPort\2~" "$dbCfgFile"
```

Note that I am suggesting a regex with `.` escaped and using capture groups and back-references to avoid repeating same text in pattern and substitution.

Similarly for second `sed` use:

```bash
tmCfgFile=~/configs/tm.properties
port=5100
sed -E -i.bak "s/^(api\.port=).*/\1${port}/" "$tmCfgFile"
```

PS: I have renamed your shell variables from all caps to camel case to avoid clash with shell env variables.

Comment: I think, that `database_name` is variable and you should change your first `sed`:
`....//127\.0\.0\.1)(/database_name)` into `....//127\.0\.0\.1)(/.*)`, or with `sed -E -i.bak "s~^(database\.url)=(.*)/(.*)~\1=\2:$mysqlContainerPort/\3~" "$dbCfgFile"`

Comment: Thanks @WalterA, yes good point. I have edited it.

Comment: @anubhava `database.properties` was successfully modified, but `tm.properties` was not even though I added $ to `tmCfgFile` (`$tmCfgFile`).

Comment: Can you show output of `cat -vte tm.properties` command by editing your question.

Comment: @anubhava Never mind, they were successfully changed, thanks a lot! It would be great if you can provide simple (even if it is repetitive) version of these commands, provided that "using capture groups and back-references to avoid repeating same text in pattern and substitution.".

Comment: Like this: `sed -i.bak "s/^api\.port=.*/api.port=${port}/" "tmCfgFile"`

Comment: Also if it worked out, [you may mark an answer as accepted by clicking on **tick mark** on top-left of the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242)

Comment: @anubhava Thanks a ton for the additional answer! I would like to mark this as the solution, but please add a dollar sign to `tmCfgFile` both in your main answer and the one in comment because it is a variable I suppose, thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my answer but cannot with comment