# my cUrl reliquishes control to the next statement before it's finished

Tags: macos, curl, sed

I'm running a script of commands (OSX) as follows

```
curl -o yahoo_IDJG.dwn http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IDJG.AS&a=10&b=8&c=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv && sed -i -e 's/^/yahoo,IDJG,xams,/' yahoo_IDJG.dwn > yahoo_IDJG.csv;
```

or

```
curl -o yahoo_IDJG.dwn http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IDJG.AS&a=10&b=8&c=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv;
sed -i -e 's/^/yahoo,IDJG,xams,/' yahoo_IDJG.dwn > yahoo_IDJG.csv;
```

unfortunately the sed starts before the curl is even finished. In fact all commands seem to start immediately.

I'm new to this so what haven't I understood ?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - note that the `&` tells your shell to run the given command in the background, then continue to the next line.  Therefore, your initial command is really running:

```
1 curl -o yahoo_IDJG.dwn http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IDJG.AS&
2 a=10&
3 b=8&
4 c=2015&
5 g=d&
6 ignore=.csv;
7 sed -i -e 's/^/yahoo,IDJG,xams,/' yahoo_IDJG.dwn > yahoo_IDJG.csv;
```

So what's happening is that the shell is parsing the command as a series of "background" processes, split up according to the `&` character.  So, it

1. runs this in the background
2. assigns the shell variable `$a` to 10 (in the background)
3. assigns the shell variable `$b` to 8 (in the background)
4. assigns the shell variable `$c` to 2015 (in the background)
5. assigns the shell variable `$g` to d (in the background)
6. assigns the shell variable `$ignore` to .csv (not in the background, but that happens very quickly as shell variable assignment is reasonably quick).
7. finally, runs a `sed` command on the yahoo.IDJG.dwn file (though creates a backup of the file with a `-e` extension on the end - check the man page for `sed` on a mac or see the discussion on [sed in-place flag that works both on Mac (BSD) and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux)) so you should have a `yahoo.IDJG.dwn` file (with the results of the sed command), a `yahoo.IDG.dwn-e` file (the original file), and (probably empty) `yahoo.IDJG.csv` file.  The solution is to enclose the entire URL in the curl command in single-quotes, and remove the `-i` from the `sed` command.

For reference, the man page for `sed` on a mac has the following:

```
-i extension
         Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It is not recom-
         mended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is
         exhausted, etc.
```

EDIT: *forgot to post the real answer!*:  Just enclose the URL in single quotes and remove the `-i` flag to the sed command:

```
curl -o yahoo_IDJG.dwn 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IDJG.AS&a=10&b=8&c=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv' && sed -e 's/^/yahoo,IDJG,xams,/' yahoo_IDJG.dwn > yahoo_IDJG.csv;
```

EDIT: If you don't care about the intermediate `yahoo_IDJG.dwn` file, you can also just pipe the curl to the sed command:

```
curl -s 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IDJG.AS&a=10&b=8&c=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv' | sed -e 's/^/yahoo,IDJG,xams,/' > yahoo_IDJG.csv;
```

When I ran that on command line, I got the same output in the .csv files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you miss the quotes, so :

```
curl -o yahoo_IDJG.dwn 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IDJG.AS&a=10&b=8&c=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv'
sed -e 's/^/yahoo,IDJG,xams,/' yahoo_IDJG.dwn > yahoo_IDJG.csv
```

And when [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is used with `-i` switch, there's no output