# sed to substitute words in a file

Tags: unix, sed

I try to learn Unix and how to use the terminal. I am in a Mac

I open the terminal, I go to a folder. Inside there is the file fruit.txt. In that file there are only the words pear, apple

I want to substitute the word pear and put mango in the file fruit.txt

```
sed 's/pear/mango/' fruit.txt
```

the terminal gives me:

```
mango, apple
```

But I open the file and nothing changed. What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look at sed‘s option -i: `man sed`

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is a *stream editor*. This means that it reads data, changes it,
and sends the result to output. It doesn’t automatically replace the
contents of a file.

`sed -i` or `sed --in-place` will replace the file as you want.

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
sed fruit.txt > newfruit.txt
```

and the output will go to a new file. This is safer; if you make a
mistake, you still have your original file.

Comment: sed -i 's/pear/mango/' fruit.txt that gives me sed:1:"fruit.txt":invalid comand code f

Comment: I also tried sed -i 's/pear/mango/' fruit.txt > newfruit.txt with the same result

Comment: What version of `sed` do you have? `sed --version`.

Comment: OP said they're on a Mac, so presumably it's BSD sed requiring `-i.bak` or similar.

Comment: @Tom Zych how can I now the version of sed? (I wrote sed --version in the terminal and it does not give me that) I am in a Mac. It seems that It is not possible to know the version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639496/how-can-i-check-the-version-of-sed-in-os-x

Comment: This works well: sed 's/oldword/newword/' file1.txt > file2.txt. Explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573368/in-place-edits-with-sed-on-os-x