# Remove leading zeros from MAC address

Tags: bash, sed

I have a MAC address that looks like this.

`01:AA:BB:0C:D0:E1`

I want to convert it to lowercase and strip the leading zeros.

`1:aa:bb:c:d0:e1`

What's the simplest way to do that in a Bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo 01:AA:BB:0C:D0:E1 | sed 's/\(^\|:\)0/\1/g;s/.*/\L\0/'
1:aa:bb:c:d0:e1
```

`\(^\|:\)0` represents either the line start (`^`) or a `:`, followed by a 0.
We want to replace this by the capture (either *line start* or `:`), which removed the `0`.

Then, a second substitution (`s/.*/\L\0/`) put the whole line in lowercase.

```
$ sed --version | head -1
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively:

```
echo 01:AA:BB:0C:D0:E1 | sed 's/0\([0-9A-Fa-f]\)/\1/g;s/.*/\L\0/'
```

This replaces `0x` (with `x` any hexa digit) by `x`.

**EDIT:** if your `sed` does not support `\L`, use `tr`:

```
echo 01:AA:BB:0C:D0:E1 | sed 's/0\([0-9A-Fa-f]\)/\1/g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Comment: I get the output  `L0`. (GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0))

Comment: [I can't tell which version of sed I have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639496/how-can-i-check-the-version-of-sed-in-os-x), but it's OSX 10.12.3. This is what ultimately worked: `echo 01:AA:BB:0C:D0:E1 | sed 's/0\([0-9A-F]\)/\1/g' |  tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`

Comment: can be done in one shot: `echo '01:AA:BB:0C:D0:E1' | sed -E 's/0*([^:]+)/\L\1/g'`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure Bash≥4 possibility:

```
mac=01:AA:BB:0C:D0:E1
IFS=: read -r -d '' -a macary < <(printf '%s:\0' "$mac")
macary=( "${macary[@]#0}" )
macary=( "${macary[@],,}" )
IFS=: eval 'newmac="${macary[*]}"'
```

- The line `IFS=: read -r -d '' -a macary < <(printf '%s:\0' "$mac")` is the canonical way to split a string into an array,
- the expansion `"${macary[@]#0}"` is that of the array `macary` with leading `0` (if any) removed,
- the expansion `"${macary[@],,}"` is that of the array `macary` in lowercase,
- `IFS=: eval 'newmac="${macary[*]}"'` is a standard way to join the fields of an array (note that the use of `eval` is perfectly safe).

After that:

```
declare -p newmac
```

yields

```
declare -- newmac="1:aa:bb:c:d0:e1"
```

as required.

Comment: `< <(printf '%s:\0' "$mac")` can be replaced by  `<<< "$mac:"`, right? Or did I land into some pitfall?

Comment: @anishsane: this wouldn't work with multiline arguments. (Which is not the case here, but it doesn't hurt to show the proper patterns).

Comment: Bash code gives me a sense of what it's like for a non-programmer to encounter any other programming language. :)

Comment: aah, `<<<` mechanism added an extra newline in the last field... Verified with `xxd`...

Answer (score 0):

A more robust way is to validate the MAC address first:

```
mac=01:AA:BB:0C:D0:E1

a='([[:xdigit:]]{2})'  ;  regex="^$a:$a:$a:$a:$a:$a$"
[[ $mac =~ $regex ]] || { echo "Invalid MAC address" >&2; exit 1; }
```

And then, using the valid result of the regex match (BASH_REMATCH):

```
set -- $(printf '%x ' $(printf '0x%s ' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}" ))
IFS=: eval 'printf "%s\n" "$*"'
```

Which will print:

```
1:aa:bb:c:d0:e1
```

Hex values without leading zeros and in lowercase.
If Uppercase is needed, change the `printf '%x '` to `printf '%X '`.
If Leading zeros are needed change the same to `printf '%02x '`.