# sed command to uncomment lines of code

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, shell, sed

Working on a build automation script and we're trying to take an input from a file called `code.js` like this:

```
var foo = {};

// var bar = 1;
// var fooBar = 2;
// var barFoo = 3;
```

And when we're done, have an output with the commented lines now uncommented with no leading spaces like this:

```
var foo = {};

var bar = 1;
var fooBar = 2;
var barFoo = 3;
```

We're trying to get the transformation saved back to `code.js` too.

So far we've tried this sed command, but our sed is no so good:

```
sed -i '' -e's/\*\//\n&/g' code.js
```

We tried using awk as well, but the leading space remains and it seems to work on the terminal, but not in the automation script for some reason:

```
awk '{sub(/\/\//,""); print}' code.js
```

We'd prefer to use sed, since we have a few sed inplace replacement commands working so far already. How can we do this in sed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's|^// ||' file
```

Comment: Getting this error: `sed: 1: "code.js": unterminated substitute in regular expression`

Any idea what it means and how to resolve?

Comment: Add your `sed` version to your question.

Comment: Chances are its a variant that requires a file name after `-i` (e.g. OSX sed?).

Comment: OSX sed :( - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639496/how-can-i-check-the-version-of-sed-in-os-x

Comment: Why did you tag your question with Linux then?

Comment: > Chances are its a variant that requires a file name after -i (e.g. OSX sed?).

That was it.

`sed -i '' -e 's|^// ||' code.js`