# Download latest file from remote server using curl

Tags: bash, curl

I'm able to download the file successfully using the following curl command.

```
curl -u user:pass -k "https://website.com/remote/path/remotefile.zip" -o /local/path/file.zip
```

Ideally, I'd like to automate this by getting the latest file programmatically. It's possible for more than one file to be uploaded per day. Each file's name is prefixed with a timestamp and there are multiple files within the directory.

Example of directory contents and filenames:

```
20191102230243952_Appended-Constant_Filename.zip
20191103040135476_Appended-Constant_Filename.zip
20191103100132360_Appended-Constant_Filename.zip
```

Update from @FedonKadifeli's comment. If a request is made to the directory containing the files, the HTML output listing the files is returned.

```
curl -u user:pass -k "https://website.com/remote/path"
```

HTML Output

```html
[...]
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="/remote/path/20191102230243952_Appended-Constant_Filename.zip"><tt>20191102230243952_Appended-Constant_Filename.zip</tt></a>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><tt>66.6 kb</tt></td>
        <td align="right"><tt>Sun, 03 Nov 2019 06:02:44 GMT</tt></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
        <td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="/remote/path/20191103040135476_Appended-Constant_Filename.zip"><tt>20191103040135476_Appended-Constant_Filename.zip</tt></a>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><tt>66.6 kb</tt></td>
        <td align="right"><tt>Sun, 03 Nov 2019 12:01:35 GMT</tt></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="/remote/path/20191103100132360_Appended-Constant_Filename.zip"><tt>20191103100132360_Appended-Constant_Filename.zip</tt></a>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><tt>66.5 kb</tt></td>
        <td align="right"><tt>Sun, 03 Nov 2019 18:01:32 GMT</tt></td>
    </tr>
</table>
[...]
```

Comment: This seems only possible if you can list the contents of the `path` folder. Does the request for URL `https://website.com/remote/path/` return the correct file list?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli It returns an HTML listing of all files within the directory. See update to question.

Comment: Something not matching. The file were named /remote/path/remotefile.zip, but the listing shows /remote/path20191103040135476_Appended-Constant_Filename.zip.

Comment: If the server is running Apache, you might have additional option on the listing: ?C=N (sort by name), and F=0 (simple listing, no HTML), which can simplify the parsing significantly.

Comment: @dash-o that was a typo on my part in scrubbing the path details, updated. Thanks for the suggestion on adding the Apache options. I can hit the URL in a browser and tried adding the parameters like so https://website.com/remote/path?C=N;F=0, but the output is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small SED script can extract the file name from the listing. Sort/head will get the latest file name

```
P=https://website.com/remote/path
curl .. "$P/" > listing.txt
LATEST=$(sed -ne '/href=/{s@.*href=".*/\([0-9]\+_[^"]\+\).*@\1@p}' < listing.txt | sort -nr | head -1)
curl ... "$P/$LATEST"
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting this when I run it, `sed: 1: "/href=/{s@.*href=".*/\( ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'`

Comment: Can you specify OS, and shell ? It works on Mint 19/Bash

Comment: You're right! I threw it on the linux server and it works as expected. I'm running macOS 10.15.0/Bash locally and that's where I run into the issue. Any idea why?

Comment: @Blaine I do not have MacOS. Can you get 'sed' & shell(bash?)version ?

Comment: For MacOS can you try simplied sed `sed -ne '/href=/s@.*href=".*/\([0-9]\+_[^"]\+\).*@\1@p'`

Comment: Here's the version of bash, 3.2.57(1)-release. Not exactly sure how to get the version of sed on a Mac. Tried the simplified version and it pulls the contents of listing.txt into output file rather than the actual file contents.

Comment: @Blaine `sed --version`

Comment: Tried `sed --version` but it doesn't seem like it's possible on a Mac, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639496/how-can-i-check-the-version-of-sed-in-os-x