# Getting conflicts in simple git revert operation

Tags: git

I have a simple *index.txt* file, and I have committed after writing each line:

```
one

two

three
```

These are my commits:

```
19b1a80 (HEAD -> master) commit three
0305c8a commit two
f534357 commit one
```

But when I'm trying `git revert 0305c8a` I'm getting this message:

```
Auto-merging index.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in index.txt
error: could not revert 0305c8a... commit two
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

I have recently started learning git, I have tried this many times with different codes but I'm not getting why this doesn't work.

Comment: [revert is a merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65867521/why-does-git-know-it-can-cherry-pick-a-reverted-commit/65868082#65868082).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO! I order for git to be able to *revert* that revision, the line that says `second` would need to be followed by EOF. Given that that is not the case anymore (because instead of EOF there is a line that says `three`), then git does not know how to proceed and that's why it is showing you the conflict. Try this:

First revision:

```
foo
bar
```

Second revision:

```
foo
second
bar
```

Third revision:

```
foo
second
bar
third
```

Then if you try to revert the second revision, it will work like a charm (because the line that was before it, `foo`, is still there... and the line following it, `bar`, is also still there).

Say that instead of reverting, you created a fourth revision with this content:

```
foo
second
blah
third
```

(so, now instead of bar, we have blah). If you tried reverting the second revision, it would break for exactly the same reason as if failed in your experiment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there is actually a separate line between any of the two line. for example, what I had written is- (line 1): one   (line 2):empty   (line 3):two   (line 4):empty.    (line 5):three and I have committed at the empty line. Then it should had worked because the line that was before two, empty-line, is still there... and the line following it, again an empty-line, is also still there! sorry if I'm not able to make my point clear.

Comment: @Mani: in that case, your original question was (slightly) defective, as you did not show the actual failing input. Be sure that you provide *everything necessary* for someone else to duplicate the problem. See [ask].

Comment: @Mani If you are adding an empty line between each one of the numbers, it is irrelevant. The idea is the same. If you added `second\n\n` in the second revision, the empty line will be followed by an EOF. By the time you want to revert it, there is _not_ an EOF there anymore but a new line saying `third` and so git doesn't know what to do about it and has to ask you to take a closer look.