# Sed "N" command multiline output with embedded newline expected result

Tags: macos, sed

I'm on macOS 12.6 and have an issue with the multiline commands in sed.

From this script (taken from the manual):
`seq 6 | sed -n 'N;l;D'` I should get this output:

1\n2$
2\n3$
3\n4$
4\n5$
5\n6$

But this is what I get:

1$
2$
2$
3$
3$
4$
4$
5$
5$
6$

I can't figure out why the newline isn't printed unambiguously (that's what the "l" command does)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce _with GNU sed v4.8_, I am getting the first output. Are you sure that you are really running the command you are running? What sed version and operating system are you using?

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm on macOS 12.6 therefor I can't tell exactly the version (or maybe yes, but not with `sed --version` as I've just read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639496/how-can-i-check-the-version-of-sed-in-os-x)). The date in the man page is June 10, 2020.

Comment: I believe macos sed is based on freebsd sed. If you look at the [manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+13.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) there is no reference to newline, so I would guess it is shown as is.

Comment: You can use gsed on `macos` with homebrew https://brew.sh/

Comment: @HatLess I ended up by doing this and adding `alias sed="gsed"` in my .zshrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the newline isn't printed unambiguously

Because you are using BSD sed, not GNU sed, the newline is printed "ambiguously".

https://github.com/chimera-linux/bsdsed/blob/master/process.c#L627 -> prints a `$`+newline on newline. (The check above when the line is longer than terminal width.)

> I should get this output:

`l` command is *not* standardized. Every sed can do what it wants with it. GUN sed prints it that way, BSD sed prints it the other, you can't expect.