# Mac os X, Sed -f and -i

Tags: macos, sed

I have an external list of replacements stored in a file   **repl.txt**
and i want to apply them to a file  **tmp.txt**  in place.

Normally, the command would be

```
sed -i -f repl.txt tmp.txt
```

but it won't work.
any hint at what syntax should i use?

Comment: probably need `-i.bak`? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux and http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3640/in-place-editing/12529/portable-use#t=201610111357373158848

Comment: also, `won't work` is too broad a thing.. would be better to tell what exactly went wrong or error msg you got if any