# Match string followed by any character followed by float number

Tags: string, sed, match

I am trying to match `bla = 0.05` and replace the number with 1234 in a file. Expected output is `bla = 1234`

Code I tried:

```
sed -i '' "s/\(bla\)\(.*\)\([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\)/#\1\21234/g" foo
```

Also, why do I sometimes need `''` and sometimes not to call `sed` ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux for usage of `-i` between different versions of sed...

Comment: for the problem you are trying to solve, can you add more sample inputs with expected output for clarity? one issue apparent is that you need to use `\?` instead of `?`

Comment: also, `.*` would consume too much... `sed -i '' 's/\(bla\)\([^0-9+-]*\)\([-+]\?[0-9]*\.\?[0-9]*\)/#\1\21234/g' foo` might help

Comment: sorry thats the only input i have for this problem

Comment: ok, what is expected output?

Comment: bla = 1234 is the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo 'bla = 0.05' > foo
$ cat foo 
bla = 0.05
$ sed 's/\(bla[^0-9.+-]*\)\([-+]\?[0-9]*\.\?[0-9]*\)/\11234/g' foo
bla = 1234
```

If extended regex option is available, either `-E` or `-r`

```
$ sed -E 's/(bla[^0-9.+-]*)([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)/\11234/g' foo
bla = 1234
```

See [sed in-place flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux) for requirements of using `-i` flag between different `sed` versions

Comment: the -E command worked. THank you very much. Im trying to figure out why my version did not work

Comment: because `.*` is [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/429/greedy-and-lazy-patterns#t=201610221644401303712) and every pattern after that can be `0` or more... for example, try this simpler command for experimenting... `echo 'bla = 0.05' | sed 's/\(bla\)\(.*\)[0-9]*/\2/'`

Comment: also `echo 'bla = 0.05' | sed 's/bla\(.*\)\([0-9]*\)/\1 abc \2/'`

Comment: i understand. If i want to match 'foo is left' whilst the string left could also be right, can i do it like this ?: 'sed -E -i '' "s/(foo[^[left]|^[right]]*)([left]|[right])/\1$ContSide/g" bar'

Comment: @Thunfisch not sure about that, would highly recommend you to go through this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean