# Recursive search and replace on directory OSX

Tags: macos, sed

I am trying to replace on any file in a directory a specific word but this doesn't work

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/oldWord/NewWord/g'
```

Subsequently I would also like to change the names of few files, but still this doesn't work

```
find . -exec rename 's/oldFileName/NewFileName/' {} ";"
```

I am using OSX terminal, any idea why?

Comment: as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux you would need `-i ''` on osx... and you don't need xargs... try `find . -type f -exec sed -i '' 's/oldWord/NewWord/g' {} \;`

Comment: for the first line I get "sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence" and for rename I get -bash: rename: command not found

Comment: Rename now works! I just did brew install rename.

Comment: Ok run export LC_CTYPE=C  and then export LANG=C before running the sed command. Problem fixed!

Comment: I think you can also do `LC_ALL=C <command>` on single command line instead of exporting...