# How to remove n characters from a specific column using sed/awk/perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix, awk, sed

I have the following tab delimited data:

```
chr1    3119713 3119728 MA05911Bach1Mafk    839 +
chr1    3119716 3119731 MA05011MAFNFE2  860 +
chr1    3120036 3120051 MA01502Nfe2l2   866 +
```

What I want to do is to remove 7 characters from 4th column. 
Resulting in

```
chr1    3119713 3119728 Bach1Mafk   839 +
chr1    3119716 3119731 MAFNFE2 860 +
chr1    3120036 3120051 Nfe2l2  866 +
```

How can I do that?
Note the output needs to be also TAB separated.

I'm stuck with the following code, which replaces from the first
column onward, which I don't want

```
sed 's/^.\{7\}//' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -anE'$F[3] =~ s/.{7}//; say join "\t", @F' data.txt
```

or

```
perl -anE'substr $F[3],0,7,""; say join "\t", @F' data.txt
```

Comment: Note the output needs to be also TAB separated. How can I modify?

Comment: @yaffle  Corrected.  Also removed the unneeded `^` anchor; matching starts there

Comment: alternatively: `perl -anE'$" = "\t"; $F[3] =~ s/^.{7}//; say "@F"' data.txt`

Answer (score 7):

```
 awk  '{ $4 = substr($4, 8); print }'
```

Comment: Note the output needs to be also TAB separated. How can I modify?

Comment: Sorry missed that requirement... `awk  'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } { $4 = substr($4, 8); print }'`

Comment: or even more concise: `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{$4 = substr($4,8)}1'`

Comment: I believe clarity is more important than conciseness.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/^(([^\t]+\t){3}).{7}/\1/' myfile.txt
chr1    3119713 3119728 Bach1Mafk   839 +
chr1    3119716 3119731 MAFNFE2 860 +
chr1    3120036 3120051 Nfe2l2  866 +
```

- `-E` use extended regular expressions, to avoid having to use `\` for `(){}`. Some `sed` versions might need `-r` instead of `-E`
- `^(([^\t]+\t){3})` capture the first three columns, easy to change number of columns if needed
- `.{7}` characters to delete from 4th column
- `\1` the captured columns
- Use `-i` option for [in-place editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux)

With `perl` you can use `\K` for variable length positive lookbehind

```
perl -pe 's/^([^\t]+\t){3}\K.{7}//' myfile.txt
```