# Drop certain characters from a column using awk

Tags: awk, sed

How to print certain number of characters from a column using awk?

I have a file which looks  like

```
00001   009 2008 00daf 
00002   00a f00b 34df1
```

I need to print

```
0000100900800daf
0000200a00b34df1
```

I know I can print columns in awk by

```
awk '{print $1 $2 $3 $4}'
```

however, I want to drop first character from column column 3. Is there a way to do it in awk?

```
awk '{print $1 $2$3$4}'
```

just prints all the columns and wont drop any characters.

Comment: See: [How to remove n characters from a specific column using sed/awk/perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46781900/3776858)

Answer (score 7):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk -v OFS= '{$3 = substr($3,2)} 1' file

0000100900800daf
0000200a00b34df1
```

Here:

- `substr($3,2)` will remove 1st character from 3rd column
- `-v OFS=` will set `OFS` to empty character

Comment: Thank you this works, I am new to awk and the way I am using it is cat file 1 | awk '{print $4$5$10$11$12} >> file2. How can I use substr here in same command line to remove first character of column 10?

Comment: Just use `awk '{print $4 $5 substr($10,2) $11 $12} file1 >> file2`

Comment: Has everything worked out?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

#### Using `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=""}{$3=substr($3,2)} 1' file
0000100900800daf
0000200a00b34df1
```

`OFS` is *Output Field Separator*, here: nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You could specify the bytes (characters) you want to keep using `cut`:

```
$ cut -b1-5,9-11,14-16,18-22 file
```

This is shorter, easier and significantly faster (4x) than the awk based solutions.

Comment: you're sure it's not the way around, thar `cut` is ***half*** the speed of `gawk` ?  :::::::  `in0:  197MiB 0:00:03 [60.6MiB/s] [60.6MiB/s] [=========>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "$__" | cut -c 23-123; )  3.23s user 0.09s system 94% cpu 3.507 total
de832c13914440529f09bd3caa61e1a6  stdin

      in0:  197MiB 0:00:01 [ 130MiB/s] [ 130MiB/s] [=========>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "$__" | gawk -e '($!NF=substr($0,23,101))^_' FS='\n'; )  1.51s user 0.07s system 88% cpu 1.775 total
de832c13914440529f09bd3caa61e1a6  stdin` :::::: `sleep 2` in btwn, and all piped in

Comment: ** that was `bsd-cut`. `gnu-cut` doesnt support `UTF-8` so it wasnt in consideration.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto That's a little hard to read. I created an ascii file with 10,000,000 lines of the sample input. cut took 0.663s (user) vs. awk 2.900s (user). Both GNU.

Comment: the one i used was `115567 133793410 207390680` - 115k rows of `UTF-8 text`, 133.8mil `UTF-8` chars, with plenty of multi-byte UTF-8 chars, spanning `197 MiB (binary-MiB)`.

Comment: In another test, of 12.5 million rows file spanning `1.85GiB` filled to the brim with multi-byte unicode, but this time testing byte-level cutting of it `1.85GiB 0:00:04 [ 446MiB/s] [ 446MiB/s] [=========>] 100%    ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "$__" | gcut -c 67-229; )  4.06s user 0.58s system 103% cpu 4.496 total d11a847206191bbddc3bf0547147d5e5  stdin`. `gnu-cut` `4.496secs total` ::: `gawk -b` byte mode : `gawk -be '{ print substr($0,67,163) } ' FS='\n'; )  3.51s user 0.59s system 103% cpu 3.945 total
d11a847206191bbddc3bf0547147d5e5  stdin` ::: `3.947 secs`  ….

Comment: ….and `mawk2` ::: `mawk2 '{ print substr($0,67,163) } ' FS='\n'; )  1.58s user 0.52s system 104% cpu 2.004 total
d11a847206191bbddc3bf0547147d5e5  stdin` barely `2.004 secs`. Letting `gnu-cut` go last made no diffference - it clocked in the same `4.496 secs`. That file is actually 12.5 million lines of de-duped song lyrics, sourcing included english korean chinese and japanese, then i used google translate to back-translate each line to the other 3 langs. You should've seen Google's face when i routed 37.5 million translation queries to them …. over the free `API` 

Comment: I didn't even needed to "circumvent Google" or "sidedoor/backdoor" through to access it via the `paid API` for free - they weren't even properly enforcing their published policy regarding daily/monthly limits on their `free API`.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto (Mmh, I don't see any multibyte chars in the sample input.) While cut just needs to copy fixed ranges of chars from in to out, awk needs to parse the entire input (find whitespace/non-whitespace transitions), create field variables, then run the program (which is copying a modified string back to $3), and then produce the output of $1..$NF. It seems obvious that cut should be able to perform better on this task than awk.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. You meant, I should be doing `-b`! Thanks, I changed it :)

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
00001   009 2008 00daf 
00002   00a f00b 34df1
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=""}{sub(/./,"",$3);print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
0000100900800daf
0000200a00b34df1
```

Explanation: I set output field separator (`OFS`) to empty string. Then I use [`sub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) string function to replace any character (`.`) with empty string, i.e. delete it, inside 3rd field. If you want to know more about `OFS` then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: This works in POSIX awk too. Nothing specific to GNU there.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v OFS= 'sub(/./,"",$3)' <<<"00001   009 2008 00daf"
0000100900800daf
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` code, written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk '
match($0,/^(\S+\s+\S+\s+).(.*)$/,arr) && gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",arr[1]) && gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",arr[2]){
   print arr[1] arr[2]
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\S(\S+)/\1/3;s/\s//g' file
```

Remove the first non-white-spaced character from the third collection of non-white-spaced characters. Then remove all white-spaced characters too.

Answer (score 1):

Another awk:

```
awk '{sub (/^./,"",$3); $0=$1 $2 $3 $4} 1' file
```

Prints:

```
0000100900800daf
0000200a00b34df1
```