# Remove everything after a certain string

Tags: bash, sed

I though this was going to be a simple task but I am having some trouble with it.

Sample input

```
$ cat file.txt
Brown Potatoes with Cheese
Yellow Potatoes with Sugar and Cheese
```

I would like to use `sed` to remove everything after the string **with**

So the output would be

```
Brown Potatoes 
Yellow Potatoes
```

I've tried this regex but it doesn't seem to work.

```
sed -i -e "s/with.*//g" file.txt
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: do you get correct output displayed if you removed the `-i` option? in that case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux ... also, a minor suggestion, you might want to remove the space before `with` as well

Comment: If I remove the -i option I get the correct output. I am puzzled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mathb@Balu:~$ sed -i.bak 's/with.*//g' file.txt
mathb@Balu:~$ cat file.txt
Brown Potatoes

Yellow Potatoes
mathb@Balu:~$
```