# Stop kubectl from printing "pod curl deleted" at end

Tags: kubectl

I am using kubectl in a script to get the current GKE cluster name like so:

```
CURRENT_CLUSTER=$(kubectl run curl --rm --restart=Never -it --image=appropriate/curl -- -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/cluster-name)
```

Unfortunately kubect prints `pod "curl" deleted` to standard output, so the result is this:

```
my-cluster-us-west1pod "curl" deleted
```

How can I stop kubectl from printing this string?

Comment: Which version of kubernetes and kubectl do you use in GKE?

Answer (score 0):

If there were a space between the cluster name and the unwanted text then you could [use awk to take the first word of the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440414/how-to-retrieve-the-first-word-of-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash):

`CURRENT_CLUSTER=$(kubectl run curl --rm --restart=Never -it --image=appropriate/curl -- -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/cluster-name | awk '{print $1;}')`

But there isn't a space so it has to be removed differently, such as using [sed to remove 'pod ' and anything after it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885110/remove-everything-after-a-certain-string):

`CURRENT_CLUSTER=$(kubectl run curl --rm --restart=Never -it --image=appropriate/curl -- -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/cluster-name | sed "s/pod .*//g")`