# sed - Find if there is nothing after a certain symbol

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Let's say I have a list of keys and values in a file as follows:

```
name=james
age=20
city=
```

How can I check this list for keys without values (i.e "city") and if there is nothing after the '=' sign, add a hash to the start of the line?

```
name=james
age=20
#city=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
sed 's/^[^=]\{1,\}=[[:space:]]*$/#&/' file
```

Explanation:

The `s` command means *substitute* and works like this:

```
s/search/replace/[optional options]
```

The patterns above are working as follows:

*search*

```
^            Begin of line
[^=]\{1,\}   1 or more non = characters
=            The =
[[:space:]]* Optional space before the end of the line
$            The end of the line
```

*replacement*

```
#            The #
&            The match from the above search
```

---

If you want to change the file in place, please check: [sed in-place flag that works both on Mac (BSD) and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux)

Comment: can also use `sed '/=[[:space:]]*$/ s/^/#/'` and mention about `-i` option for inplace editing

Comment: @Sundeep Good alternative! About `-i`, unless the OP mentions it itself in the question I don't recommend it in order to avoid destroying anybody's data. (You never know who picks this up after a quick Google search without carefully reading the question and answer)

Comment: yeah that's good point, I usually link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux

Answer (score 1):

Using **awk**

```
awk -v FS="" '$NF=="="{$0="#"$0}1'
```

If last field is `=` then prepend `#`

OR

```
awk -v FS="=" '$2==""{$0="#"$0}1'
```

If second field `$2` is `null` then prepend `#`

Output:

```
name=james
age=20
#city=
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'=' '$2==""{sub(/^/,"#")}1' infile

#OR

awk -F'=' '$2==""{print "#" $0;next}1' infile

#OR

awk -F'=' '{print ($2==""?"#":"") $0}' infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat infile
name=james
age=20
city=

$ awk -F'=' '$2==""{print "#" $0;next}1' infile
name=james
age=20
#city=

$ awk -F'=' '{print ($2==""?"#":"") $0}' infile
name=james
age=20
#city=

$ awk -F'=' '$2==""{sub(/^/,"#")}1' infile
name=james
age=20
#city=
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try that

```
cat myfile| sed 's/\(.*.=\s*$\)/#\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

One more awk

```
awk -F= '!$2{$0="#"$0}1' infile
```

Comment: That would fail if `$2` evaluates numerically to zero. See [@batMan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46907103/1745001) for the right approach.