# while using sed to replace string, the changes are not applied in files

Tags: unix, sed

```
sed -i s/oldstr/newstr/g
```

I want to replace all old string with new string in a directory. When I executed this command, It shows all strings are changed to new string on console. But when I entered into file and checked, Old string still remains same. Please help to figure the issue

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, what did you pass to this `sed` command ? Which Input_file(s) or `*` you have put please let us know on same.

Comment: depending on your sed version, you may have to use `-i` option differently - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux.... also, as a good practice, use single quotes around the command `sed -i.bkp 's/oldstr/newstr/g'`

Comment: Did you try `cat file | sed -i 's/oldstr/newstr/g'`? Use the file as an argument `sed -i 's/oldstr/newstr/g' file`

Answer (score 0):

```
#> sed -i \.orig 's/old/new/g'  file
```

That should be the same as:

```
#> mv file file.orig 

#> sed 's/old/new/g' file.orig > file.
```

Comment: Thanks.
Why is sed ‘s/old/new/g’ * not changing the string in all files(apparently  sed ‘s/old/new/g’ file.orig > file works fine)

Comment: Might be to prevent us from trashing a bunch of files and having to access backups...d8)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are in macos you could try:

```
sed -i '' 's/oldstr/newstr/g' your-file
```

From the man:

> Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.

So by using `-i ''` it will not create a backup and apply changes to your file.

to keep a backup this could be used:

```
sed -i.bak 's/oldstr/newstr/g' your-file
```

To replace the `oldstr` in multiple files you could use this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/oldstr/newstr/g' *
```

To keep a backup:

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's/oldstr/newstr/g' *
```