# Replace or trim using Python / Bash regex

Tags: python, regex, bash

I have an XML document that has entries that contains URL, basically a Git / Bitbucket URL:

```
<value>
https://git...com/projects/.../..._config.json?raw&amp;at=dev
</value>
```

So basically this URL points to the dev branch, and I want to replace it such that it points to master by removing the `"&amp;at=dev"` string.

How do I trim this using regex using the suffix `"_config.json?raw"` as reference? Can you give both Python and bash script solution? How about when `"at=dev"` is to be replaced with `"at=release"`? (Please note that I cannot just replace all occurence of `"dev"` as the word is too common, so I still need to use `"_config.json?raw"` as regex reference)

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a pretty simple *positive lookbehind* scenario.  [Read more here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: You can try `re.sub("(_config.json\?raw.*at=)dev","\\1release",t)` where t is your string

Answer (score 0):

with `sed`

```
sed -E 's/(config.json\?raw)&amp;at=dev\b/\1/' file
```

note that you have to escape the question mark.

Comment: What's the difference between `sed -e` and `sed -E`? I'm trying to use `sed -i` to modify the file but I get some error. Same error results from `sed -e`.


`invalid reference \1 on 's' command's RHS`

Comment: they are different options. `-E` is to enable regex for `\1` substitution.  Perhaps try `-r` instead.

Comment: @menorah84 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275070/sed-not-giving-me-correct-substitute-operation-for-newline-with-mac-difference/