# Line-specific reordering of words with awk

Tags: string, awk, pattern-matching

Assume a multi-line text file with two alternating types of lines. The first line starts with ">" and contains alphanumerical strings separated by underscores. The second line consists of a single alphanumeric string.

```
$ cat file
>foo_bar_baz1
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>foo_bar_baz2
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>foo_bar_baz3
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

I would like to change the order of the words in those lines starting with ">".

```
$ cat file | sought_command
>baz1_foo_bar
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>baz2_foo_bar
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>baz3_foo_bar
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

I understand that this task can be done with *awk*.

How would I need to change the below draft *awk* code to achieve my objective? In its current form, the below code only prints lines starting with ">", but not those without.

```
awk -F'_' '$1 ~ /^>/ { print ">"$3"_"$1"_"$2}' file | sed 's/>foo/foo/'
>baz1_foo_bar
>baz2_foo_bar
>baz3_foo_bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. The `1` will print all lines, while only the desired lines will be modified:

```
$ awk -F'_' '$1 ~ /^>/ {$0 = ">"$3"_"$1"_"$2}1' file | sed 's/>foo/foo/'
>baz1_foo_bar
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>baz2_foo_bar
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>baz3_foo_bar
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

You might prefer to use substr instead of piping to sed:

```
$ awk -F'_' '$1 ~ /^>/ { $0 = ">" $3 "_" substr($1,2) "_" $2}1' file
>baz1_foo_bar
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>baz2_foo_bar
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>baz3_foo_bar
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl, though this solution is good for given Input_file but if length of line is more than examples then it may cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you for N number of fields to handle in `>` lines in Input_file.

```
awk '/^>/{sub(/>/,"");num=split($0,a,"_");for(i=num;i>=1;i--){val=val?val OFS a[i]:a[i]};print ">"val;val="";next} 1' OFS="_"  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
/^>/{
  sub(/>/,"");
  num=split($0,a,"_");
  for(i=num;i>=1;i--){  val=val?val OFS a[i]:a[i]  };
  print ">"val;
  val="";
  next}
1
' OFS="_"   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `sed` alone

```
$ sed -E 's/^>(.*)_([^_]+)$/>\2_\1/' ip.txt
>baz1_foo_bar
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>baz2_foo_bar
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>baz3_foo_bar
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

- `-E` to enable extended regular expressions (some versions may need `-r` option instead)

  - use `sed 's/>\(.*\)_\([^_]*\)$/>\2_\1/' ip.txt` if ERE is not supported
- `^>(.*)_([^_]+)$` here `^` and `$` are start and end of line anchors. `_([^_]+)$` allows to capture the last string after `_` and `(.*)` will have rest of the string
- `>\2_\1` re-order as needed
- for in-place editing, see [sed in-place flag that works both on Mac (BSD) and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux)