# Unable to remove control @ from file

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file which has ^@ in it and I am unable to remove it using `sed` or `replace` command in python. I can see `^@` only when I open the file in vi editor. Please suggest. Below is what i tried using sed.

> sed 's/^@/?/g' filename

Comment: looks like the file is a binary file. ^@ is probably the null character. Good luck processing that with `sed`

Comment: Yeah, i tried all ways using sed and replace to read it but couldn't read. Please suggest other ways which can read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on Linux, not sure if syntax varies elsewhere, try

```
$ printf 'abc\0baz\n' | cat -v
abc^@baz
$ printf 'abc\0baz\n' | tr -d '\0' | cat -v
abcbaz
```

`tr` will delete all ASCII NUL characters from input.. `cat -v` is used here to highlight non-printing characters

for file input, use `tr -d '\0' <filename`

GNU sed (and possibly few other implementations) allow to use hex value to represent a character

```
$ printf 'abc\0baz\n' | sed 's/\x00//g' | cat -v
abcbaz
```

so, for in-place editing, use `sed -i 's/\x00//g' filename` (See also: [sed in-place flag that works both on Mac (BSD) and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux) )