# sed command won't run on mac with current sed version

Tags: sed

I am running the following command

```
sed -i \
    -e "s/\[project\]/${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}/" \
    -e "s/\[model-name\]/${MODEL_NAME}/" \
    -e "s/\[model-version\]/${MODEL_VERSION}/" \
    ${HOME}/cloudml-apigee-serving/apiproxy/targets/default.xml
```

returns

```
sed: -e: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed in-place flag that works both on Mac (BSD) and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with an argument after `-i`:

```
sed -i '' .....
```