# Find a pattern, use and substitution for another match

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have the following string. I would like to find the first occurrence of digits in a line, use this match to replace the NULL's.

```
INSERT INTO data VALUES (11,1), (NULL,2), (NULL,3), (NULL,4);
```

I'm really not familiar with sed or awk at all.

so in the example above this is the output i want.

```
INSERT INTO data VALUES (11,1), (11,2), (11,3), (11,4);
```

this is kinda pseudo of the issue i think
awk '{ sub(/{digit}/, "NULL", capturegroup }'

```
while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
    echo $line  |  
    awk '
    match($0,/\([0-9]+/){
      value=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
    }
    {
      gsub("NULL",value)
    }
    1' >> converted.sql
done < test.sql
```

Comment: By seeing your profile came to know you never select any answer as correct answer, I would like to suggest you to please give it sometime and try to select an answer as correct one out of all posts. Even for your previous threads too you could do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed` (tested on **GNU sed 4.2.2**, syntax will vary for different implementations)

```
$ cat ip.txt
INSERT INTO data VALUES (11,1), (NULL,2), (NULL,3), (NULL,4);
foo (42,14), (4,NULL), (5,3), (NULL,14)

$ sed -E ':a s/([0-9]+)(.*)NULL/\1\2\1/; ta' ip.txt
INSERT INTO data VALUES (11,1), (11,2), (11,3), (11,4);
foo (42,14), (4,42), (5,3), (42,14)
```

- `-E` to use ERE instead of default BRE
- `:a` label `a`
- `([0-9]+)(.*)NULL` first sequence of digits, followed by other text, followed by last occurrence of `NULL` in the line
- `\1\2\1` as per expected output
- `ta` branch to label `a` if the substitution succeeded
- See [sed in-place editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux) if you need to change the input file itself

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
echo "INSERT INTO data VALUES (11,1), (NULL,2), (NULL,3), (NULL,4);"  |  
awk '
match($0,/\([0-9]+/){
  value=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
{
  gsub("NULL",value)
}
1'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
INSERT INTO data VALUES (11,1), (11,2), (11,3), (11,4);
```

As per OP's comment in case you want to perform this operation for an Input_file then do following.(simply pass Input_file name to `awk` script)

```
awk '
match($0,/\([0-9]+/){
  value=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
{
  gsub("NULL",value)
}
1' Input_file
```

Comment: actually i'm gonna ask another think i would like to do this line by line from a file?

Comment: while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
    echo $line  |  
    awk '
    match($0,/\([0-9]+/){
      value=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
    }
    {
      gsub("NULL",value)
    }
    1'
done < test.sql

Comment: @muscleman71, please check my additonal comments now in my answer and let me know then?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Perl also

```
$ cat muscleman.txt
INSERT INTO data VALUES (11,1), (NULL,2), (NULL,3), (NULL,4);
INSERT INTO data VALUES (22,1), (NULL,2), (NULL,3), (NULL,4);
INSERT INTO data VALUES (33,1), (NULL,2), (NULL,3), (NULL,4);
$  perl -pe ' /(\d+)/ and $x=$1; s/NULL/$x/g ' muscleman.txt
INSERT INTO data VALUES (11,1), (11,2), (11,3), (11,4);
INSERT INTO data VALUES (22,1), (22,2), (22,3), (22,4);
INSERT INTO data VALUES (33,1), (33,2), (33,3), (33,4);
$
```

Thanks @Sundeep for another shorter answer!

```
$ perl -pe '($x)=/(\d+)/; s/NULL/$x/g' muscleman.txt
INSERT INTO data VALUES (11,1), (11,2), (11,3), (11,4);
INSERT INTO data VALUES (22,1), (22,2), (22,3), (22,4);
INSERT INTO data VALUES (33,1), (33,2), (33,3), (33,4);
$
```

Comment: if you are a fan of golfing: `perl -pe '($x)=/(\d+)/; s/NULL/$x/g'`

Comment: @Sundeep glad that you liked it..I'll add yours to the answer.. btw I tried ````perl -pe ' /(\d+)/ && s/NULL/$1/g '```` why it didnt work?.

Comment: I think that is because the substitute command will change `$&`, `$1`, etc

Comment: OK.. but it didn't introduce any capture groups in s/// - so it shouldn't change right?

Comment: when you get time pls try golfing qstn - 54242508

Comment: every regex will have at least the default `$&` set.. and as far as I know, `$1`, `$2` will always change on any use of regex

Comment: ok.. got you.. thank you.. and pls review 54246409 and provide suggestions for any improvement..