# sed replace 1 line in file with all lines in file

Tags: sed

Lets say I have a line `#SYM`

I need to replace it with all lines from file1.txt

Is it possible to do that with sed?

I have tried `sed 's/#SYM/file1.txt/' updater`

But that doesn't work, because I need to load file1.txt as string, and I do not know how to do that.

EDIT: I believe that there could be a way to do it in a shell script somehow.

EDIT2: I also just tried this:

`#!/bin/bash
value=$(<tools/symlink)
sed -i 's/#SYM/$value/' META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `r` command:

```
sed -e '/#SYM/ {r tools/symlink' -e 'd}' META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script
```

- `/#SYM/ {r tools/symlink` if a line contains `#SYM`, append the contents of `tools/symlink`
- `d}` then delete the matching line
- the two commands are separated using `-e` option because everything after `r` is considered as part of filename

Add the `-i` option once you are satisifed that it is working

Comment: its working, but if i add -i, it says sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unexpected `}'

Comment: are you using `GNU sed` or some other implementation? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux