# bash shell execution

Tags: bash, sed

I am using

sed -s n v

Nothing works for me

Comment: Do you get an error? if so, add that message to the question. Which version of `sed` are you using, `GNU sed` or something else? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The -i flag is only in GNU Sed.

```
cat file | tr ']' '[' > temp
mv temp file
```

The above should work for you.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Problem is that the script is exited before the sed command executed.

Comment: The `i` flag is not only in GNU sed.